# Print a sinusoidal wave (vertically)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Print a continuous sinusoidal wave scrolling vertically on a terminal. The program should not terminate and should continuously scroll down the wave (except until it is somehow interrupted). You may assume overflow is not a problem (i.e. you may use infinite loops with incrementing counters, or infinite recursion).

The wave should satisfy the following properties:

- Amplitude = 20 chars (peak amplitude)
- Period = 60 to 65 lines (inclusive)
- The output should only consist of spaces, newline and `|`
- After each line of output, pause for 50ms

Sample output:

```
                    |
                      |
                        |
                          |
                            |
                              |
                                |
                                 |
                                   |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                   |
                                  |
                                |
                               |
                             |
                           |
                         |
                       |
                     |
                   |
                 |
               |
             |
            |
          |
        |
       |
     |
    |
   |
  |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
      |
        |
         |
           |
             |
               |
                 |
                   |
                     |
                       |
                         |
                           |
                             |
                              |
                                |
                                  |
                                   |
                                    |
                                      |
                                      |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                    |
                                   |
                                  |
                                |
                               |
                             |
                           |
                         |
                       |
                     |
                   |
                 |
               |
             |
           |
          |
        |
       |
     |
    |
   |
  |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
       |
        |
          |
            |
             |
               |
                 |
                   |
```

The above output should go on forever unless otherwise interrupted, e.g. SIGINT or SIGKILL, or closing terminal window, or you power off your machine, or the Sun swallows the Earth, etc.

Shortest code wins.

Note. I am aware of a similar problem on [Display Scrolling Waves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11940/display-scrolling-waves) but this isn't exactly the same. In my problem, the wave is not to be scrolled "in place" - just output it on a terminal. Also, this is an ascii-art problem, so don't use Mathematica to plot it.

Comment: Peak amplitude, peak-to-peak amplitude, or root-square amplitude?

Comment: Peak amplitude.

Comment: @David The Ecuador makes it pretty obvious. :-P

Comment: Is it ok to draw a wave with just |s and no spaces?

Comment: @Gelatin Yes it is ok.

Comment: Can a specific standard terminal width be assumed (e.g. 80)?

Comment: @maxwellb Terminal width is unspecified, i.e. do whatever you want :)

Comment: @ace Wait, if I were to replace every space character in your sample output with `|`, it would be a valid program? You shouldn't say this because it changes the question.

Comment: @Quincunx it's not a wave then, is it?

Comment: @ace Then why [your response](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18633/print-a-sinusoidal-wave-vertically?noredirect=1#comment36506_18633) to [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18633/print-a-sinusoidal-wave-vertically?noredirect=1#comment36465_18633)?

Comment: @Quincunx Oh... I thought using no spaces mean something like `printf("%*c")`... sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: All answers yet are invalid. They also stop for SIGKILL not just for SIGINT.

Comment: @Max Ried fine, I will change it to "should go on forever unless otherwise interrupted".

Comment: ...or the Sun swallows the Earth, or the galaxy suffers from heat death, or highly intelligent beings tamper with the space time continuum

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### APL (35)

(Yes, it does fit in 35 bytes, [here's a 1-byte APL encoding](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00907z.pdf))

```
{∇⍵+⌈⎕DL.05⊣⎕←'|'↑⍨-21+⌈20×1○⍵×.1}1
```

Explanation:

- `{`...`}`1: call the function with 1 at the beginning
- `1○⍵×.1`: close enough for government work to `sin(⍵×π÷30)`. (`1○` is `sin`).
- `-21+⌈20`: normalize to the range `1..40` and negate
- `'|'↑⍨`: take the last `N` characters from the string `'|'` (which results in a string of spaces with a `|` at the end
- `⎕←`: display
- `⌈⎕DL.05`: wait 50 ms and return `1`. (`⎕DL` returns the amount of time it actually waited, which is going to be close to `0.05`, rounding that value up gives `1`).
- `∇⍵+`: add that number (`1`) to `⍵` and run the function again.

Comment: Darn... I thought trigonometric functions plus the time delay would leave you guys out

Comment: Here a 33 char one: `{⎕←'|'↑⍨-⌈20×1+1○⍵⋄∇.1+⍵⊣⎕DL.05}0`

Comment: @ace LOL. You should check APL out, it's not a novelty language. It's very old and has been in use in large systems for decades. It's quite unique, compared to anything else. IMHO the symbols make it much more readable that the ASCII-only derivatives (J)

Answer (score 23):

### C, <del>74</del> <del>73</del> <del>70</del> <del>69</del> 67 characters

67 character solution with many good ideas from @ugoren & others:

```
i;main(j){main(poll(printf("%*c|\n",j=21+sin(i++*.1)*20,0),0,50));}
```

69 character solution with while loop instead of recursion:

```
i;main(j){while(printf("%*c|\n",j=21+sin(i++*.1)*20,0))poll(0,0,50);}
```

Approaching perl territory. :)

Comment: This was inspired by @ace's own C answer.

Comment: I think you could use `5E4` instead of `50000`.

Comment: I think you could use *.1 instead of /10.

Comment: @musiphil, I also thought about using 5E4, but it turns out that it does not work: Without showing the compiler `usleep()` prototype, you would have to explicitly cast the 5E4.

Comment: @moala, thanks! Using *.1 instead of /10 seems to work.

Comment: @treamur: Thanks for the info. I also considered the possibility of a type error, but pre-ISO C was so archaic that I couldn't figure out the rules exactly. :)

Comment: You can cut out two more characters by moving the assignment to j into the printf, like this: `printf("%*s\n",j=21+sin(i++*.1)*20,"|")`. The resulting type is still int so it's a valid field width argument.

Comment: One more character by replacing `usleep(50000);` with `poll(0,0,50);`.

Comment: `"%*s"`, where have you been all my life? +1 just for that.

Comment: @Art, totally awesome, thanks! Implemented both of your ideas. I had been thinking of poll() myself, but I mistakenly landed my eyes on ppoll() parameter list on the manual page, so I discarded the idea. I was too hasty. Very nice that you brought the idea up again. :)

Comment: `main(poll(!printf(...),0,50));` saves a character.

Comment: @ugoren, totally so! Thank you for the tip. :)

Comment: @treamur - Two ugly ideas - 1. Omit `!` (with 0 FDs, `poll` doesn't use the pointer). 2. Use `%*c|` with 0 (prints invisible NUL characters).

Comment: @ugoren, brilliant ideas again, thanks! I added them to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica <s>121 104 80 67</s> 64

```
n=1;While[0<1,Spacer[70 Sin[n Pi/32]+70]~Print~"|";Pause@.05; n++]
```

[image: sine]

Comment: question says not to use mathematica to plot it.  is this different than that somehow?

Comment: @Malachi Yes. This uses mathematica to calculate it, just like any other answer. Using mathematica to plot would be telling mathematica to plot `x=20*sin(pi*y/30)+20` or something similar.

Comment: ok I get what you are saying thank you for the clarification

Comment: Clever rule-bending :)

Comment: +1, but as written you have 75 chars including whitespace. And  `n=1;While[1==1,Spacer[70 Sin[n Pi/32]+70]~Print~"|";Pause@.05;n++]` is 66 chars.

Comment: And here is a 58 char version `Do[Spacer[70*Sin[n*Pi/32]+70]~Print~"|";Pause@.05,{n,18!}]`

Comment: Im not a Mathematica user, but i think you can change `1 == 1` to `0 < 1` to decrease 1 char.

Comment: @CCP 2   Yes, you are correct! Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

### Perl, 48 (68)

GNU sleep version: 48

```
print$"x(25+20*sin).'|
';$_+=.1;`sleep .05`;do$0
```

Cross platform: 68

```
use Time::HiRes"sleep";print$"x(25+20*sin).'|
';$_+=.1;sleep.05;do$0
```

Removed the use of Time::HiRes module by using shell sleep function.
Shortened increment as per Ruby example.
Shortened using $" and $0 seeing hints from Primo's work
Thanks for hints Primo.

Comment: I saved this as a file `test.pl` and ran `perl ./test.pl`, however the waiting time does not match the specification. Also, the amplitude of the wave is too small. (This amplitude refers to the length between the peak and the equilibrium position.)

Comment: I guess if I changed the increment from .105 to .1 I would beat ruby at 56 chars!

Comment: @primo - my shell sleep does do times shorter than 1 second...

Comment: `man sleep` → `unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);`. It won't error, but the actual sleep interval is zero. Some suggestions to make yours shorter: change `$d` to `$_`, and then use `(25+20*sin)`, and change the `\n` for a literal newline.

Comment: @primo `man 1 sleep` on a GNU/Linux bash shell tells us that `Unlike most  implementations  that require NUMBER be an integer, here NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating point number.`

Comment: @ace good to know.

Comment: I left the GNU sleep version running on my PC over the weekend. I thought you might like to know that it leaked 5GB memory

Comment: Shocking news!!! I guess the do$0 is the culprit. But it saves a byte instead of putting it in a block and calling redo at the end of the block...

Answer (score 11):

### Perl - 64 (or 60) bytes

*The following uses a Windows-specific shell command:*

```
`sleep/m50`,print$"x(20.5-$_*(32-abs)/12.8),'|
'for-32..31;do$0
```

*The following uses a GNU/Linux-specific shell command:*

```
`sleep .05`,print$"x(20.5-$_*(32-abs)/12.8),'|
'for-32..31;do$0
```

Both at 64 bytes.

- Period is 64.
- Maximum amplitude is exactly 20.
- The curve is perfectly symmetric.
- Every period is identical.

```
                    |
                      |
                         |
                           |
                             |
                               |
                                |
                                  |
                                   |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                    |
                                   |
                                  |
                                |
                               |
                             |
                           |
                         |
                      |
                    |
                  |
               |
             |
           |
         |
        |
      |
     |
    |
   |
  |
 |
 |
|
|
|
|
|
 |
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
      |
        |
         |
           |
             |
               |
                  |
                    |
                      |
                         |
                           |
                             |
                               |
                                |
                                  |
                                   |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                    |
                                   |
                                  |
                                |
                               |
                             |
                           |
                         |
                      |
                    |
                  |
               |
             |
           |
         |
        |
      |
     |
    |
   |
  |
 |
 |
|
|
|
|
|
 |
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
      |
        |
         |
           |
             |
               |
                  |
                    |
```

Note that this isn't exactly a sinusoidal wave, but rather a quadratic interpolation. Plotted against an actual sin:

[image]

At the granularity required, these are visually indistinguishable.

If the aesthetics aren't so important, I offer a **60 byte** alternative, with period length 62, maximum amplitude of ~20.02, and slight asymmetries:

```
`sleep/m50`,print$"x(20-$_*(31-abs)/12),'|
'for-31..30;do$0
```

Comment: This isn't a sinusoidal wave; it is simply parabolas (if I read your code right). (If you can represent this with some sinusoidal wave, I'd love to see the function).

Comment: Sine is a formula, if you replicate the formula it is still a Sinusoidal wave. and this is probably a variant of Sine in some fashion.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby 56

```
i=0
loop{puts" "*(20*Math.sin(i+=0.1)+20)+?|;sleep 0.05}
```

Comment: Is replacing puts with p allowed?

Comment: @Slicedpan I think I won't, since this is a challenge to draw something. `p` will add double quotes around around each line and alter the "drawing".

Answer (score 7):

## Befunge 98 - <s>103</s> 100

```
:1g:02p' \k:02gk,'|,a,$ff*:*8*kz1+:'<\`*
468:<=?ABDEFGGGHGGGFEDBA?=<:86420.,+)'&$#"!!! !!!"#$&')+,.02
```

Cheers for a program that does this, in a language without trigonometric capabilities; the first program in fact. The second line is simply data; the character corresponding with the ascii value of the sin, added to a space character.

**EDIT:** I saved 3 chars by not subtracting the space away; the sinusoid is translated 32 units to the right (which is valid).

Befunge also does not have a sleep command, or something similar. It would be nice to find a fingerprint, but I couldn't find one, so `ff*:*8*` pushes `8*225**2` (`405000`) and `kz` runs a noop that many times (well, that many times + 1). On windows command line with [pyfunge](http://mearie.org/projects/pyfunge/), this turns out to be about 50 milliseconds, so I say I'm good. Note: if anyone knows a good fingerprint for this, please let me know.

The last part of the code simply checks if the counter (for the data line) is past the data, if it is, the the counter is reset to 0.

I used [this](http://ideone.com/om176B) to generate the data.

---

## Taylor Series

Although this version is 105 chars, I just had to include it:

```
:::f`!4*jf2*-:::*:*9*\:*aa*:*:01p*-01g9*/a2*+\$\f`!4*j01-*b2*+:01p' \k:01gk,$'|,a,ff*:*8*kz1+:f3*`!3*j$e-
```

I was trying to shorten my program, and decided to look at the [taylor series for cosine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20cos%28x%29) (sine is harder to calculate). I changed `x` to `pi * x / 30` to match the period requested here, then multiplied by `20` to match the amplitude. I made some simplifications (adjusted factors for canceling, without changing the value of the function by much). Then I implemented it. Sadly, it is not a shorter implementation.

```
:f`!4*jf2*-
```

checks whether the values of the taylor series are getting inaccurate (about `x = 15`). If they are, then I compute the taylor series for `x - 30` instead of `x`.

```
:::*:*9*\:*aa*:*:01p*-01g9*/a2*+
```

is my implementation of the taylor series at `x = 0`, when `x` is the value on the stack.

```
\$\f`!4*j01-*
```

negates the value of the taylor series if the taylor series needed adjustment.

```
b2*+
```

make the cosine wave positive; otherwise, the printing would not work.

```
:01p' \k:01gk,$'|,a,
```

prints the wave

```
ff*:*8*kz1+
```

makeshift wait for 50 milliseconds, then increment `x`

```
:f3*`!3*j$e-
```

If `x` is greater than 45, change it to -14 (again, taylor series error adjustment).

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I'm looking forward to, hope you can golf it down :)

Comment: There! I successfully decreased the code length by -5 chars! And there is still room for improvement!

Comment: @Quincunx my perl solution also does not use any built in trig functions ;)

Answer (score 6):

## Python, <del>108</del>,<del>93</del>,<del>90</del>,<del>89</del>,88

```
import math,time
a=0
while 1:print" "*int(20+20*math.sin(a))+"|";time.sleep(.05);a+=.1
```

Now with infinite scrolling :)

Edit: ok, 90. Enough?

Edit:Edit: no, 89.

Edit:Edit:Edit: 88 thanks to [boothby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2180/boothby).

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made the question clear - your program should not terminate and should continuously scroll down the wave (except until SIGINT)

Comment: `a=0.` -> `a=0` gets you to 88

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 59 characters

```
<?for(;;usleep(5e4))echo str_pad('',22+20*sin($a+=.1)).~ƒõ;
```

Comment: You can save yourself some bytes by using `echo ...;` in place of `fwrite(STDOUT,...);`.

Comment: That makes sense when calling from the command line anyway. 10 characters saved - thanks primo.

Comment: 58: `<?for(;;)echo~str_pad(ƒõ,22+20*sin($a+=.1),ß,usleep(5e4));`

Comment: Very nice. I won't edit my answer with those changes, you should post as your own.

Comment: Is this verified to work? It doesn't work on http://ideone.com/6gmtfl , nor does it work on my computer. (Although it does print a sine wave with the error message)

Comment: @ace it needs to be saved with an ansi encoding. ideone automatically converts everything to utf-8, which breaks. `~ƒõ` is just shorthand for `"|\n"`.

Comment: @AlexBarrett the difference isn't significant enough to warrent a separate answer. I just like to see PHP do well. If you prefer, you can add it to your own as "a 58 byte variant suggested by primo" or some such ;)

Answer (score 5):

## C64 BASIC, 64 PETSCII chars

[image]

On a PAL C64, `For i=0 to 2:next i` cycles for approx. 0,05 seconds, so the delay time is respected.

Answer (score 4):

## C - 86+3 characters

**Thanks shiona and Josh for the edit**

```
i;main(j){for(;j++<21+sin(i*.1)*20;)putchar(32);puts("|");usleep(50000);i++;main(1);}
```

<s>i;main(j){for(j=0;j++<20+sin(i/10.)*20;)putchar(32);puts("|");usleep(50000);i++;main();}</s>

float i;main(j){for(j=0;j++<20+sin(i)*20;)putchar(32);puts("|");usleep(50000);i+=.1;main();}

Compiled with the `-lm` flag, I assume I need to add 3 chars

Comment: Would it work if you made i an int and just divided it by 10.0 (or 9.9 to save a char?) within the call to sin()? `i;main(j){for(j=0;j++<20+sin(i/10.0)*20;)putchar(32);puts("|");usleep(50000);i++;main();}`

Comment: You can bring the size down to 76 characters or so by using printf() to replace the for loop: `printf("%*s\n",(int)(21+sin(i++/10.)*20),"|")`

Comment: Hmm... I would feel really guilty if I use this idea in my answer, especially when this is my own question... Would you consider posting an answer yourself?

Comment: You can shave off two more characters if you remove the `j=0`:
`i;main(j){for(;j++<21+sin(i/10.)*20;)putchar(32);puts("|");usleep(50000);i++;main(1);}`.  This relies on the assumption that the program is called with 0 arguments.

Comment: Most conversations regarding interpreter/compiler flags have resolved with each flag used costing a byte, but the `-` before being free.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript <del>88</del> <del>76</del> 78 characters

```
setInterval('console.log(Array(Math.sin(i++/10)*20+21|0).join(" ")+"|")',i=50)
```

Based on Kendall Frey's code.

Comment: You never initialize `i`, so it prints a straight line instead of a wave.

Comment: My mistake... It probably worked because I had ran Kendall's script already in my console, so i was initialised already for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Ti-Basic, 33 bytes**

```
While 1:Output(8,int(7sin(X)+8),"!":Disp "":π/30+X→X:End
```

**The following caveats exist**:

1. Due to screen limitation of 16x8, this sine wave only has an amplitude of 7 (period of 60 is still maintained)
2. Due to lack of an easy way to access the `|` char, `!` is used instead
3. Due to lack of an accurate system timer, the delay is not implemented.  However, run speed appears approximately correct.

Comment: Heh, since TI-BASIC is counted in one-/two- byte tokens, this is actually 33 bytes (not "56 chars"), so it actually should have won the challenge!

Comment: Except for the amplitude thing...

Comment: Well, yes, but going by bytes it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript - 88

```
setInterval(function(){console.log(Array(Math.sin(i++/10)*20+21|0).join(" ")+"|")},i=50)
```

I'm sure someone can come up with something that's actually clever.

Answer (score 2):

## J - <del>103</del>,<del>58</del>,<del>57</del>,54

Thanks to awesome guys from IRC

```
(0.1&+[6!:3@]&0.05[2:1!:2~' |'#~1,~[:<.20*1+1&o.)^:_]0
```

In words from right to left it reads: starting from 0 infinite times do: sin, add 1 ,multiply by 20, floor, append 1 (so it becomes array of 2 elements), copy two bytes ' |' correspondingly, print it, wait 0.05s and add 0.1

Instead of infinite loop we can use recursion, it would save 2 characters, but will also produce a stack error after some number of iterations

```
($:+&0.1[6!:3@]&0.05[2:1!:2~' |'#~1,~[:<.20*1+1&o.)0
```

Where `$:` is a recursive call.

Comment: Would you mind adding a little explanation, so that people unfamiliar with the J syntax (like me) can also understand your answer?

Comment: It's possible to shorten this to 50 characters by fussing about with the train's structure: `(+2*(%20)6!:3@[2:1!:2~' |'#~1,~[:<.20*1+1&o.)^:_]0`. The recursion version only saves 1 char this time `$:@(+2*(%20)6!:3@[2:1!:2~' |'#~1,~[:<.20*1+1&o.)0` though it appears to last longer before bottoming out.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell - 75

```
main=putStr$concat["|\n"++take(floor$20+20*sin x)(repeat ' ')|x<-[0,0.1..]]
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't get the program to pause 50 ms without doubling my char count, so it just floods the console, but it does produce the sine wave.

---

Here's the full code with pausing (138 chars with newlines):

```
import GHC.Conc
import Control.Monad
main=mapM_(\a->putStr a>>threadDelay 50000)(["|\n"++take(floor$20+20*sin x)(repeat ' ')|x<-[0,0.1..]])
```

Comment: Pausing was one of the requirements. Can you also post the code with the pause?

Comment: Okay, I posted it.  I wish Haskell let you pause code without imports.

Comment: By amplitude I mean the peak amplitude, i.e. twice the amplitude of your current program. You may wish to change it to `20+20*sin x` instead to qualify.

Comment: Oh, sure.  I guess I misinterpreted that part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>fugly</sub> **Javascript - 77**

```
i=setInterval("console.log(Array(Math.sin(i+=.1)*20+20|0).join(' ')+'|')",50)
```

and if we do it in Firefox - **73**

```
i=setInterval("console.log(' '.repeat(Math.sin(i+=.1)*20+20|0)+'|');",50)
```

and if we're nasty - **67**

```
i=setInterval("throw(' '.repeat(Math.sin(i+=.1)*20+20|0)+'|');",50)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6: 46 chars

```
sleep .05*say ' 'x(25+20*.sin),'|'for 0,.1...*
```

Create an infinite lazy Range using `0,0.1 ... *`, loop over that. `say` returns `Bool::True` which numifies as 1 in multiplication, this way I can keep it in a single statement.

Comment: I can see why `sleep` and `.05` have to be separated. But I wonder if the space between `say` and `' '` is mandatory?

Comment: Yes :s It gives "2 terms in a row" error for `say' '` One can use `say(' ')` but that's 1 char extra in this case...

Comment: @Matthias: In Perl 6, listops either have to not take arguments, have a space after them, or use parenthesis. It's not a language designed for code golf, unlike Perl 5 (but it contains many nice builtin features, so it's usable).

Comment: @xfix Thank you for the explanation. I like the language, but I did not look into it thoroughly yet, because I still cannot use it in a work project yet. However, I always plan to write some Perl 6 scripts. @ Ayiko, I appreciate your Perl 6 posts :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 103

Stupid frikk'n imports...

```
import time,math
t=0
while 1:t+=(.05+t<time.clock())and(print(' '*int(20+20*math.cos(t*1.9))+'|')or.05)
```

Rather than "sleep", this implementation grinds at the cpu because python makes it easier to get a floating-point cpu clock than wall clock.  This approach won't beat [friol's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18640/2180), but it's fun so I'm leaving it up.

Answer (score 1):

## C#

The Magic Line [91] Characters

```
for(var i=0d;;Console.Write("{0,"+(int)(40+20*Math.Sin(i+=.1))+"}\n",'|'))Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Working Program Below. [148] Characters

```
namespace System{class P{static void Main(){for(var i=0d;;Console.Write("{0,"+(int)(40+20*Math.Sin(i+=.1))+"}\n",'|'))Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);}}}
```

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made the question clear - your program should not terminate and should continuously scroll down the wave (except until SIGINT). Also, please add a character count.

Comment: Sorry forgot about that bit. Fixed now.

Comment: I think you can lose "Thread.Sleep"s and change "float" with var :) 117 chars. -- Sorry didn't see the wait time.. 133 chars now.

`using System;class P{static void Main(){for(var i=0d;;Console.Write("{0,"+(int)(40+20*Math.Sin(i+=.1))+"}\n",'|'))Thread.Sleep(50);}}`

Comment: Yes I thought about changing it to var but wasn't sure about making changes after I got a +1. The reason I used Fully Qualified names is Thread uses the System.Threading namespace so it would have to be `using System;using System.Threading;class P{static void Main(){for(var i=0d;;Console.Write("{0,"+(int)(40+20*Math.Sin(i+=.1))+"}\n",'|'))Thread.Sleep(5‌​0);}}` This ends up longer I think

Comment: Made the change by not using FQN's for Console and Math it saves 1 char. Also using var saves another 2 chars :-}

Comment: I'm just upvoting answers that I have verified to be correct. Feel free to shorten your code as long as the output is the same :)

Comment: I counted 150 characters for your working program. It's possible to shrink it to 148 by sticking the whole thing into the `System` namespace: `namespace System{class P{static void Main(){for(var i=0d;;Console.Write("{0,"+(int)(40+20*Math.Sin(i+=.1))+"}\n",'|'))Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);}}}` see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184/4163

Comment: Ha nice one Bob. I wouldn't have thought about that.

Comment: I can't get it to compile in VS2010 with `Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)` am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I was able to get it to run, but I had to add some Brackets and Semi-colons and it doesn't look the same every period

Comment: Compilation failed on gmcs also after direct copy-and-paste of the sourcecode due to Unexpected character. I retyped the sourcecode on a new file and it works again. I guess there is some non-printable character hidden in this code, leading to the compilation error.

Comment: There must have been a hidden character added when I pasted the code here. It is fixed not. Also Malachi there is nothing wrong with the number of ')' and '}' characters and their placement. The only thing that is wrong is your understanding that you can place a statement inside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <del>92</del>,<del>89</del>,87

```
def f(i:Int){println(" "*(20+20*math.sin(i*.1)).toInt+"|");Thread sleep 50;f(i+1)};f(1)
```

Comment: `(20+20*math.sin(i*.1))` reduces it by 1 char, assuming this is valid syntax (I have no experience with Scala)

Comment: Thanks, but I have just discovered that myself :)

Answer (score 1):

## C#

**[152]** Characters

```
namespace System{class P{static void Main(){for(var i=0d;;){Console.Write("{0,"+(int)(40+20*Math.Sin(i+=.1))+"}\n",'|');Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);}}}}
```

I could not get the Existing C# answer to Run and I couldn't downvote because I don't have enough Reputation

it was missing a couple of `{` and missing a `)` after the For Loop Declaration.

I figure that the variance in the look of the wave when it is run is because of the way we are trying to display this wave.

---

if we aren't counting the Namespace and the Method Declaration then it would be 
**[104]** characters for the working version

```
for(var i=0d;;){Console.Write("{0,"+(int)(40+20*Math.Sin(i+=.1))+"}\n",'|');Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);}
```

Comment: The other C# answer works on gmcs. It fails to compile at first, but I think it is because there is some non-printable character in the source code. After typing it again on an empty file, the compilation is successful.

Comment: Compilers can be picky, huh?

Answer (score 1):

## VB <strike>[236]</strike>[178]

not sure how you would count the tabs,  I just took the count from Notepadd++ before I pasted here.  **newlines are mandatory, probably why no one likes using it for code golfing.**

```vb
Module Module1
Sub Main()
Dim i
While True
Console.WriteLine("{0:" & (40 + 20 * Math.Sin(i = i + 0.1)) & "}", "|")
Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
End While
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash+bc (to do the math), 80

```
$ for((;;i++)){ printf "%$(bc -l<<<"a=20*s($i/10);scale=0;a/1+20")s|
";sleep .05;}
                |
                 |
                   |
                     |
                       |
                         |
                           |
                            |
                              |
                               |
                                |
                                 |
                                  |
                                   |
                                   |
                                   |
                                   |
                                   |
                                   |
```

Answer (score 1):

### Julia - 68

Edit: thanks to  M L and ace.

```
i=0;while 0<1;println(" "^int(20sin(.1i)+20)*"|");i+=1;sleep(.05)end
```

Well, it can not compete vs APL, but here's my attempt.

Output:

```
                    |
                      |
                        |
                          |
                            |
                              |
                               |
                                 |
                                  |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                    |
                                   |
                                  |
                                |
                              |
                             |
                           |
                         |
                       |
                     |
                   |
                 |
               |
             |
           |
         |
        |
      |
     |
    |
   |
  |
 |
|
|
|
|
|
 |
 |
  |
   |
     |
      |
       |
         |
           |
             |
              |
                |
                  |
                    |
                      |
                        |
                          |
                            |
                              |
                                |
                                 |
                                   |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                    |
                                   |
                                 |
                                |
                              |
                            |
                          |
                        |
                      |
                    |
                  |
                 |
               |
             |
           |
         |
       |
      |
     |
   |
  |
  |
 |
|
|
|
|
|
 |
  |
  |
    |
     |
      |
        |
         |
           |
             |
               |
                 |
                   |
                     |
                       |
                         |
                           |
                            |
                              |
                                |
                                 |
                                   |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                    |
                                  |
                                 |
                               |
                              |
                            |
                          |
                        |
                      |
                    |
                  |
                |
              |
            |
           |
         |
       |
      |
    |
   |
  |
 |
 |
|
|
|
|
|
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
      |
        |
          |
           |
             |
               |
                 |
                   |
                     |
                       |
                         |
                           |
                             |
                              |
                                |
                                  |
                                   |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                    |
                                  |
                                 |
                               |
                             |
                            |
                          |
                        |
                      |
                    |
                  |
                |
              |
            |
          |
         |
       |
      |
    |
   |
  |
 |
 |
|
|
|
|
 |
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
       |
        |
          |
            |
             |
               |
                 |
                   |
                     |
                       |
                         |
                           |
                             |
                               |
                                |
                                  |
                                   |
                                    |
                                      |
                                      |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                      |
                                      |
                                     |
                                   |
                                  |
                                |
                               |
                             |
                           |
                         |
                       |
                     |
                   |
```

Comment: I don't know Julia, but is it possible to use `.05` instead of `0.05` in `sleep`?

Comment: Actually yes! Thanks

Comment: Cut it down to **68 characters**:  `i=0;while 0<1;println(" "^int(20sin(.1i)+20)*"|");i+=1;sleep(.05)end`———`sin(i/10)*20` is equal to `20sin(.1i)`

Comment: I don't know Julia, but could you use a for loop iterating over all the natural numbers instead?

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 30 bytes

Small size improvement over the other answer, at the cost of some accuracy. Note that TI-Basic technically has the | character, but you have to transfer it via computer or use an assembly program to access it.

```
While 1
Output(8,int(8+7sin(Ans)),":
Disp "
.03π+Ans
End
```

Comment: Woah, did not see how old this challenge was! Was going to try to golf this more (which is definitely possible) but it's really not worth it...

Comment: By the way, `.03π` can be `.1`, which is still within the required interval.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks! Do you see any way I could golf the output command? Also, since I have a CSE, I could get this to the right amplitude (26-char screen) at the cost of a few bytes.

Comment: No, the output command looks fine--too bad the Disp needs a quote. The amplitude should be 20 chars, actually, making the screen width requirement 39. So it would only work on the graph screen, and there's no short way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 81 bytes

```
t=0;while(fprintf('%s\n',i))i=[];t=t+1;i(fix(21+20*sind(t*6)))='|';pause(.05);end
```

I abused the fact that `i` is always initialized in MATLAB, which meant that I could put the `fprintf` in the `while` statement without initializing `i` first. This does mean the program first outputs an empty line, but I think this is not forbidden in the spec.

Furthermore, it abuses the fact that Matlab will ignore most ASCII control characters, printing a space instead of NULL (also for the first empty line).

Comment: _"I abused the fact that i is always initialized in MATLAB, which meant that I could put the fprintf in the while statement without initializing i first."_ Really clever! +1!

Answer (score 0):

### F# - <s>90</s> <s>79</s> <s>77</s> 76

Here's a solution using recursion

```
let rec f x=printfn"%*c"(int(20.*sin x)+21)'|';Thread.Sleep 50;f(x+0.1)
f 0.
```

It could probably be improved further.

Comment: Without knowing anything about F#, I'm assuming that Thread.Sleep expects a value in ms, so you can get rid of one of the 0's and do Thread.Sleep 50. :)

Comment: @ValarDohaeris You're right. I misread the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

### AutoHotkey 176

```
SetKeyDelay,-1
run Notepad.exe
WinWaitActive, ahk_class Notepad
p:=0
loop
{
sleep 50
p+=Mod(Floor(A_index/40),2)?-1:1,t:=""
loop % p
t .= " "
sendinput % t "|`n"
}
esc::Exitapp
```

Run the script . It opens Notepad and prints the characters. Press Esc anytime to exit.

Answer (score 0):

**Clojure, 121**

Short version:

```
(loop[a 0](println(clojure.string/join(repeat(int(+ 20 (* 20 (Math/sin a)))) " ")) \|)(Thread/sleep 50)(recur(+ a 0.1)))
```

Pretty version:

```
(loop [a 0]
  (println (clojure.string/join (repeat (int (+ 20 (* 20 (Math/sin a)))) " ")) \|)    
  (Thread/sleep 50)
  (recur(+ a 0.1)))
```

Period is 64.

Type this into `lein repl` or save in file `sin.clj` and run with `lein exec sin.clj` (requires lein-exec plugin).

Answer (score 0):

**Groovy 87 Chars**

Okay, now for a serious answer that actually follows the guidelines

```
def x=0;while(true){println ' '*(20*Math.sin(x)+20)+'|';x+=0.1;Thread.sleep(50)}
```

Comment: Do you think a suitable decimal approximation for `Math.PI/30` can save you a few chars?

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 42 bytes

CJam is a bit younger than this challenge, but since this submission doesn't beat APL anyway, I don't see a problem with that.

```
es{es1$m50>{500d/ms21*K+S41*\i'|tN+oes}*}h
```

This won't work in the online interpreter, so you'll have to use [the Java one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/).

The basic idea is to keep a timestamp on the stack, and whenever 50 ms have passed since the last timestamp, a new line is printed (where the sine is computed from that last time), and a new timestamp left on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

## Pascal: 99 characters

```pascal
uses Crt;var i:Real;begin
repeat
Writeln('|':Round(Sin(i)*20+21));i:=i+0.1;Delay(500)until 0=1;end.
```

Another task where Pascal's output formatting comes handy and everything else is pain.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 60 chars

Unlike CCP’s solution, mine uses a recursive function:

```
a(n)=(print(" "^int(20sin(.1n)+20)*"|\n");sleep(.05);a(n+1))
```

Example:

```
julia> a(1)
                      |
                        |
                          |
                            |
                              |
                               |
                                 |
                                  |
                                    |
                                     |
                                      |
                                       |
                                       |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                       |
                                       |
                                      |
                                     |
                                    |
                                   |
                                  |
                                |
                              |
                             |
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 44 bytes

```
@L
A=A+.1?" "*(COS(A)*20+20);"|
WAIT 3GOTO@L
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 57 bytes

```powershell
for(;;sleep -m 50){' '*(20*[math]::Sin(($i+=.1))+20)+'|'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SMPaujgnNbVAQTdXwdRAs1pdQV1Lw8hAKzo3sSQj1soqODNPQ0MlU9tWz1BTU9vIQFNbvUa99v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
['|NT/Å½20*21+ú,50.W
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Wr3GL0T/cOuhvUYGWkaG2od36Zga6IX//w8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
[               # Start an infinite loop:
 '|            '#  Push character "|"
 N              #  Push the 0-based loop-index
  T/            #  Divide it by 10
    Å½          #  Take the sine of that
      20*       #  Multiply it by 20
         21+    #  Add 21
            ú   #  Pad that many leading spaces before the "|"
                #  (`ú` will ignore any decimal digits and interpret it as an integer)
             ,  #  Pop and print this string with trailing newline
 50.W           #  Sleep 50 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Open your browser's console.

```
50i@Ol|ùMsU°/A Ñ0+21
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=NTBpQE9sfPlNc1WwL0Eg0TArMjE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>92</del> 82 bytes

Saved bytes thanks to the comments.

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDsIgEADQ3a@4MAFNCHStDI6dHZyxPdIzSEkh1QT5dnwvLy64vj9fuBS4U8SHOxHwWzCuGW4pQe0revC2nu4Asnr6bBSQ09VoI2o6KJYQOQMm@WgG/nZlU5kiJ6mMkKMWquxzLGJgPyYmGqxprftL638)

```scala
def f={var i=0;while(i<101){println(" "*(21+(math.sin(i*.1)*20).toInt)+"|");i+=1}}

//math.sin
//scala.math.sin
//Math.sin
//java.lang.Math.sin
//WHATEVER
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xT8NADIX3@xVPmS5UulwqsSAydGSmiBEdiVEcpU50cVok6G8PFwhDB9t67322PNWhD8vCp3GIimlV7hS0dW/mxqsHqecYSdQ1cwzKgyTEDO8d1YpnFnoNZwJ9Kkkz4TCO@DLAOUQwKniTREMfCMLp/C9s8we8CGuKVxQoikvLPcFqnCnfzM3ix6r0/t9cD/fo0ua@xA52YrGMO3hX5mnsfe50eBLd4DGyaC82Q5bSLm1k31m@hYxdhXITRXFsI4XGTT3RaO/9H3U1a6V28765mmX5AQ)

```scala
import scala.math._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object SineWave extends App {
  var i = 0

  def animateWave(): Unit = {
    //while (true) {
    while (i<=100) {
      val j = 21 + (sin(i * 0.1) * 20).toInt
      println(" " * j + "|")
      i += 1
      //Thread.sleep(50)
    }
  }

  animateWave()
}
```

Comment: I think you should be able to do `math.sin` instead of `scala.math.sin`. Also, I think `f` can be `def f=`, not sure if that's allowed though.