# Anti-golfscript anti-golf: create a task where GolfScript or J is outgolfed by your (conventional) lang

Tags: popularity-contest, metagolf, golfscript

You need to make three things:

1. Statement of a task, **T**.
2. Solution of the task in language not typically used for golfing, **A**.
3. Solution of the task in language typically used for golfing, **B**. Don't try to just bloat up **B** to pump up the score, instead think as if **B** was written by your competitor.

Use common sense in defining `typically used for golfing`, try to maximize fun for other users.

Other users may propose better `B`s (maybe including in other "golfy" languages).

Scoring is `(length_in_bytes(B)+5)/(length_in_bytes(A)+5)`, more is better. (Maybe the scoring formula should be changed?..)

The main idea is to invent a task where languages that typically perform well in codegolf meet a problem. It can be sudden strength of a usual language in the given task or sudden weakness of some golflang.

Avoid tasks that mention specific programming languages, like `Input a string and execute it as a Scheme code`.

Comment: I suppose that you make this a popularity-contest instead of a code-golf. Otherwise people will complain that it is not a "shortest-code-wins".

Comment: OK, changing to popularity-contest. You can also suggest better title or better scoring.

Comment: I assume my previous question qualifies? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18633/print-a-sinusoidal-wave-vertically The perl solution is 48 chars while the J solution is 54 chars

Comment: Numerator is supposed to be minimum of length_in_bytes for all suitable B's.

Comment: @ace, Yes, linking to existing specific problems with specific solutions is OK; can be posted as answer (copied summary of the statement + links to **A** and **B**)

Comment: Do we get to specify lang B (as long as it is good at golfing)? Or can anyone say "here is a program in language <insert language name> and it has a very short solution of length <n>:"?

Comment: @Quincunx, As it currently has "popularity-contest", bending "use common sense to decide what is golf language and what is not" rule is just expected not to be upvoted.

Comment: @Vi. Wasn't trying to bend that rule; just wondered if anyone can say "here is a shorter version in MY language" and wreck the score.

Comment: @Quincunx, If the task is based on "A suprising strength of some **A**" then yes; if on "A suprising weakness of some language for **B**" then no. The alternative solution can be posted in comments in any case, so others can calculate alternative score.

Comment: BTW some languages like Perl can be both on A side and on B side, depending on context.

Comment: What if it's extremely difficult to do on B? I have `perform OCR` in mind which mathematica can do as shown here http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17094/8766 but would be very difficult in languages not specifically built for it

Comment: @user80551, Then provide a proof that **B** 1. there exists implementation of the task in **B**; 2. each implementation of the task in **B** must take not less than N characters.

Comment: @Vi. See the edit

Comment: @user80551, OCR? There can't be short and golfable OCR algorithms? Actually you may write something like `I believe it can't be done in less than 5000 bytes on languages B1, B2 or B3`. If other savvy user disagrees, he/she may provide a counterexample (shorter working solution in B). This is less funny although...

Comment: Why was this closed as off-topic? It seems to have an objective winning criterion to me?

Answer (score 14):

My previous question, Print a sinusoidal wave (vertically), qualifies at this moment. I'm posting it here as a solution, also hoping that you guys can come up with some shorter solutions to my original question.

As required by Vi., I will post a summary of the question.

Print a continuous sinusoidal wave scrolling vertically on a terminal. The program should not terminate and should continuously scroll down the wave (except until SIGINT). You may assume overflow is not a problem (i.e. you may use infinite loops with incrementing counters, or infinite recursion).

The wave should satisfy the following properties:

- Amplitude = 20 chars (peak amplitude)
- Period = 60 to 65 lines (inclusive)
- The output should only consist of spaces, newline and `|`
- After each line of output, pause for 50ms

There is a sample output on my original question, but I'm not posting it here, because this will make my answer ridiculously long. My original question can be seen here: [Print a sinusoidal wave (vertically)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18633/print-a-sinusoidal-wave-vertically)

Shortest `A` currently: a Perl solution with 48 chars:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18655/12205

```
print$"x(25+20*sin).'|
';$_+=.1;`sleep .05`;do$0
```

Shortest `B` currently: a J solution with 54 chars: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18649/12205

```
($:+&0.1[6!:3@]&0.05[2:1!:2~' |'#~1,~[:<.20*1+1&o.)0
```

Currently, the score of this answer is 1.113 (an awfully low score)

Comment: The current score according to current formula is approximately 1.113

Comment: @Vi. should I delete this answer or should I wait some time and see what happens? If the latter, how long should I wait?

Comment: The statement states bytes, not characters. Converted to UTL-8, the APL solution made 61 bytes (70 for UTF-16).

Comment: You're claiming that Perl is not a language typically used for golfing, but it's the language which was first associated with the word *golf*! Ruby, at 56, looks like the real language A in the current answers to your questions.

Answer (score 8):

## Add two numbers

Get two numbers from STDIN, and add them together. You have to support floating point numbers, so 0.5 + 1.5 has to equal 2.

### Perl 5 (with `-E`)

```
say<>+<>
```

### GolfScript

```
n%'+'*'"#{
}"'n/\*~
```

Comment: Calculated score as `(24+5)/(8+2+5) = 1.9(3)`. `-E` also counted as program bytes.

Comment: The same comment as I made to ace: you're claiming that Perl is not a language typically used for golfing, but it's the language which was first associated with the word *golf*!

Comment: And your GolfScript program doesn't work. A working program would be `n%'+'*'"#{
}"'n/\*~` where the character between `{}` is a literal newline (not supported in comments).

Comment: @PeterTaylor, Compared with GolfScript, Perl is a "usual" language; compared with Java, it's a "golf" language.

Comment: Score using PeterTaylor's golfscript variant: `1.6`. I can although successfully run neither of variants with my GolfScript interpreter (md5 = 8bb179c2eb47060026a9a598a4263900).

Comment: The J for this isn't too bad, actually: `+/".1!:1,~1`. APL would probably be even smaller.

Comment: In Pyth, this is just `s.Q`, and in O, `jj+`.

Answer (score 8):

## Print 'Hello, World!' to the stdout.

PHP, 13 bytes

```
Hello, World!
```

Golfscript, 15 bytes

```
'Hello, World!'
```

Pyth, 14 bytes

```
"Hello, World!
```

Comment: Nicely topical. :)

Comment: New B: In HQ9+ `H`

Comment: But it's spelt incorrectly, @NotthatCharles

Comment: @georgeunix Good point.  You capitalized your "W".

Answer (score 7):

### Score 48/37 or 1.(297)

T: write a code snippet that ends the program after exactly one hour (as close as possible, like within a second) of running. Don't worry about exceptions, they can be unhandled.

A: Java (32)

```
Thread.sleep(3600000);int a=1/0;
```

B: is for Befunge 98, requires the [TIME fingerprint](http://www.rcfunge98.com/rcsfingers.html#TIME) (43)

```
"EMIT"4(HMS00p01p02p#;gS-!01gM-!H-!++3-!j;@
```

This takes the Hour, Minute, and Second at the time of running, and puts the at cells 02, 01, and 00. Then, it skips over the `;` to the second part. The second part works as follows:

```
g          get the value at 00
"EMIT"4(S) get the current time in seconds
-!         subtracts the values and changes a 0 to 1, anything else to 0
```

similarly for the Minute and Hour.

```
++  sums up the values
3-! i the sum is 3, we get a 1, otherwise, we get a 0.
j   jump over the next that many cells
;   skip code execution until the next ;
@   end program
```

Note that Befunge will automatically go back to the beginning of the line when the end of a line is reached.

---

As we can see, Befunge is not good when it comes to waiting for specific times. However, Java is not bad.

Comment: thought I'd make the code difference even bigger; now it is clear who is better.

Comment: APL: `⎕DL 3600`

Comment: Java usually reads as `class Main{public static void main`...

Comment: @Vi. see "code snippet". Basically, it requires the code that actually does the work, not more than that.

Comment: @marinus okay APL is good too, but Befunge is not.

Comment: This task is still a valid answer. To sleep in the GNU/Linux bash shell (as `A`), `sleep 1h` works, and is still shorter than (by byte count, otherwise of the same length as) the APL solution by @marinus :)

Comment: Python's `import time\ntime.sleep(3600)` is also OK (as **A**) and is 28 bytes.

Comment: @Vi. Ah, but python can be quite good at golfing. The Java code is also valid, so I'll keep it as that.

Comment: Tcl: `after 3600000`. Why do people bring brainfuck to claim that a certain task is hard to golf in a regular golf language?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn What are you talking about? Befunge (I'll assume that is what you meant) is **the** language I golf in.

Comment: I don't know Befunge, but the Java snippet doesn't "end the program" as required by the spec. That would require either a `System.exit(0);` or wrapping your sleep in a `main` method.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Rather than the verbose `System.exit(0)`, I can use `int a=1/0` to terminate by exception. The Befunge snipped does end the program; eventually, the IP will reach the `@`.

Comment: @Quincunx Why can't you just remove the `int a=` part?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Fails to compile: `error: not a statement`

Comment: Your befunge code isn't golfed well enough. You can just do `"EMIT"4(` at the beginning of your program, rather than every single time you need to get the time. Fixing this problem qould reduce your score to 1.3

Comment: Also, I don't think you need self-modifying code for this.

Comment: In addition, your befunge will fail if run when the hour, minute, or second is exactly 59 (the ascii value of ';')

Answer (score 5):

## Output a certain text file (498.388888 points)

The goal output is [here](https://bpaste.net/show/a1ba772bec0a).

The Python 3.4.3 script to print it is 49 bytes:

```
for b in dir(__builtins__):print(eval(b).__doc__)
```

The naive CJam program equal to the goal output, by wrapping the output string in `"..."` and escaping each `"` that occurs in it, would be 26908 bytes.

Comment: Very clever, though it may run afoul of the "specific languages" restriction (which is vague, admittedly).

Comment: The closest rule is "avoid mentioning specific language". Python is not mentioned, but is clearly meaned.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is a bit tongue-in-cheek, I sort of just wanted to point out that the rule is sort of a slippery slope. Imagine if I had "mangled" the output more -- say, taking the SHA1 checksum of each docstring -- it would be very weird to claim "this garbled bunch of hex digits is too language-specific" :)

Comment: If I wanted to do a more "fair" answer, I'd probably use Mathematica. You can do a lot of extremely domain-specific things in it that would take thousands of bytes of CJam/Pyth/anything else. But sadly, I don't  know the language.

Comment: Link to output is dead.

Answer (score 4):

## Say "Hello world!" (50 / 26 ≈ 1.92)

Show a message box to say "Hello world!"

### JavaScript

```
alert('Hello world!')
```

In a browser with support for DOM Level 0+.

### Perl

```
use Win32;Win32::MsgBox('Hello world!','',48)
```

Running on ActivePerl with Win32::GUI.

Comment: `alert` isn't inherently part of JS, and the GolfScript program is just a comment.

Comment: I've changed the answer to use plain Perl.

Answer (score 3):

## Output "Hello world!" until user presses "q", <s>1.842</s> 105/44 = 2.386

1. Print "Hello world!" (including newline).
2. The user presses a key, which is not echoed to the screen.
3. Repeat until the key pressed was "q".

### QBasic (<s>52</s> 39 characters)

```
1?"Hello world!":IF"q"<>INPUT$(1)THEN 1
```

Since posting my original answer, I discovered that I could turn off autoformatting in QB64. :^D With the line number and `?` shortcut for `PRINT`, this looks rather like a ternary expression in C-like languages.

First version:

```
PRINT "Hello world!"
IF INPUT$(1) <> "q" THEN RUN
```

### Perl 5 (100 characters)

```
while("q"ne$e){print"Hello world!\n";system"stty cbreak -echo";$e=getc;system"stty -cbreak echo";}
```

The above will only work on (certain?) UNIX systems (tested on Ubuntu 12.04). It's possible that one could go cross-platform and get it down to 91 characters using the [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm) module, but I haven't tested it:

```
use Term::ReadKey;while("q"ne$e){print"Hello world!\n";ReadMode 3;$e=ReadKey 0;ReadMode 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Hello, world (3 1/3 points)

Write program that outputs `Hello World.`.

### HQ9+ (1 character)

This is not language "typically used for golfing", so I believe it fits here. Works in [this interpreter, by the way](http://www.almnet.de/esolang/hq9plus.php).

```
H
```

### GolfScript (15 characters)

I doubt it can get any shorter, even if it's GolfScript.

```
"Hello World."
```

Comment: I don't think `HQ9+` suits as **A** language. It is designed for tricks/riddles/fun. Brainfuck/unlambda/other esoterical languages also does not seem to suit as **A**.

Comment: @Vi.: But it's not _typically_ used for golfing.

Comment: You can hovewer try to use `HQ9+` as **B** language and beat it by Java or such...

Comment: Looks like there's a hierarchy: Compared to Java, Perl's a golflang. Compared to Perl, GolfScript is a golflang. Compared to GolfScript, HQ9+ is a golflang...

Comment: @Vi.: I carefully checked your task description. HQ9+ is never used for golfing, except for two particular tasks - "99 bottles", and "Hello, world". Unless you can show some other task in which HQ9+ wins with any other programming language, I still think it fits the definition, even if it abuses it (hey, it's [tag:popularity-contest]). HQ9+ is simply not used for golfing stuff not related to those two tasks. So, it's not _typically_ used for golfing. The second is obviously designed for CodeGolf - it's GolfScript.

Comment: OK, considering it as "the best abuse of rules" nomination.

Comment: @xfix one more case where HQ9+ is the best at golfing: Quines (when disallowing the empty program)

Comment: @Quincunx: Here, I win in GolfScript, Befunge, and PHP - `1`. You wouldn't tell me that PHP is golfing language, and yet it has a short quine. Actually, in PHP, any single character is a quine.

Comment: @xfix That is not a quine in Befunge.

Comment: @Quincunx: Uhm, yeah, my mistake. Well, bc then.

Comment: @Vi compared to Java, *anything's* a golflang.

Answer (score 0):

### Output "Hello world!", 33/97 = 2.94

Write a program that outputs `Hello world!`

### Arduino or GML

```
Serial.print("Hello world!")
```

or

```
show_message("Hello world!")
```

Both are 28 characters.

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/gtb)

I use GTB for golfing a lot (especially since I created it myself, and it is Turing complete). Unfortunately, there is only limited support for lowercase characters (because TI-84 calculator can't deal with it). This is probably the shortest GTB program that can output Hello world!

```
S;"lower",1,1)→_~"H"+S;"expr(",1,1)+_+_+S;"cos(",2,1)+" W"+S;" or ",2,2)+_+S;" and ",4,1)+"!
```

92 characters.

Comment: Does GTB version also output it to serial port?

Comment: Is GTB version intentionally bloated up with various `cos`s and `exprs` or it genuintely can't just output something in regular way? Or `"` character is actually not a string literal and confusing me...

Comment: @Vi. It's not bloated up at all... it has to strip e from expr, two l from lower, o from cos, or from or, l from lower, and d from and.

Comment: 'Other users may propose better Bs (maybe including in other "golfy" languages). ' --- let me try golfscript: `"Hello world!"`

Comment: @JanDvorak You're probably right.

Comment: Never thought I'd see GML used here.

Comment: @ipi I've used it in several other answers.

Comment: TI-BASIC's lowercase Hello World program is just `"Hello, world` with lowercase letters typed in using some sort of utility; additionally sub( does not work like that.

Comment: Umm yeah, not sure what I was thinking when I wrote this answer, sorry about that.