# Blinking twelve

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, animation

Many electronic devices, specially old ones, will show a blinking `12:00` when the time has not been set. The purpose of this challenge is to recreate this.

Specifically, the task is to **display `12:00` and `--:--` alternatively in an infinite loop**.

The **period** should be 1 second, divided evenly in two periods of 0.5 seconds. Here "1 second" and "evenly" can be interpreted loosely. For example, it is acceptable if the code pauses for 0.5 seconds between displaying the strings, even if the resulting period will then be a little higher than 1 second. An initial pause before displaying the first string is acceptable.

Each new string can be displayed either by [**replacing the former string**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqWzT.gif) or [**in a new line**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vhiR.gif). Trailing whitespace is allowed, except that if each new string is on a different line there should be no empty lines between consecutive strings.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: does this count as [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]?

Comment: @FlipTack I think so, but I wasn't sure. Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't think so, I think the KG tag is mostly for a fixed string. This has more to it, the waiting and alternating strings.

Comment: Can submissions wait 0.5 seconds before showing initial output?

Comment: @FlipTack Yes, edited

Comment: IMHO, the statement "Each new string can be displayed either by replacing the former string or in a new line" made this challenge not fun.

Comment: @Setop Do you mean that I should have required replacing the strings instead of allowing each string on a new line? Well, some languages or interpreters have difficulty with the concept of clearing the screen or deleting previous output; that's why I gave some flexibility

Comment: Question! Would it be okay as answer to use DOS as platform and exploit the text-mode's feature of blinking for this?

Comment: @z0rberg's I think it would, yes. Please provide a gif with the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
.“12:00“--:--”ṄœS¥€ß
```

### How it works

```
.“12:00“--:--”ṄœS¥€ß  Main link. No arguments.

.                     Set the return value to 0.5.
 “12:00“--:--”        Yield ["12:00", "--:--"].
                 ¥    Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain.
              Ṅ       Print the left argument.
               œS     Sleep as many seconds as the right argument specifies.
                  €   Map the created dyadic chain over the string array, with
                      right argument equal to the return value, i.e., 0.5.
                   ß  Recursive call the main link.
```

Comment: So you;re basically turning both strings in the list into links of their own, with an added sleep-command? Sweet.

Answer (score 34):

### HTML/CSS, <s>131</s> <s>108</s> <s>106</s> 101 + <s>18</s> 17 = <s>149</s> <s>126</s> <s>125</s> <s>123</s> 118 bytes

```css
a{background:#FFF;margin:-5ch;animation:a 1s steps(2,start)infinite}@keyframes a{to{visibility:hidden
```

```html
<tt>--:--<a>12:00
```

Edit: Saved 23 bytes thanks to @insertusernamehere. Saved 1 byte by switching from `<pre>` to `<tt>`. Saved 2 bytes thanks to @darrylyeo. Saved 5 bytes thanks to @DBS.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Bah, I golfed away the `a{position:absolute}` but completely forgot about the `pre`...

Comment: Do you still need the pre tag? the css only mentions a.

Comment: @ev3commander I saved a byte by switching to `<tt>`.

Comment: You can remove the final `}}` completely.

Comment: I think you should be able to simplify `margin-left` to `margin` since you're working from the top left anyway `margin:-5ch;` should have the same effect.

Comment: @DBS Thanks, I think it works because the text gets aligned on the baseline so the top and bottom margins don't have a visible effect.

Answer (score 16):

## Shell and `pv`, 26 bytes

This use `yes` standard tool and `pv` *Shell pipeline element to meter data passing through*

```
yes '12:00
--:--'|pv -qlL2
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the language should probably be stated as "Shell and pv", since (to my knowledge anyway) pv isn't included in any shell nor is it part of the GNU or BSD core utilties.

Comment: That's a nice trick ! (which I believe was pioneered by @Digital Trauma [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104382/61904) ).

Albeit in this case it feels a bit against the spirit of the challenge,
as the mission statement was to "display 12:00 and --:-- alternatively" (imitating a blinking display), but this code will just output character by character at a constant rate of 12 chars per second instead.

Which means that "12:00" will stay on the screen only for 1/12 (0.08) seconds  ("12:0_"=1/12s=>"12:00"=2/12s=>"-").

Comment: @zeppelin thanks for references: I'v used @DigitalTrauma's sample  `-qlL2` for making  2 lines by secs instead of  `-qL12`: 12 chars by sec. Length of script is same

Answer (score 15):

## Octave, <s>63</s> <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 55 bytes

```
c='--:--00:21';while c=flip(c)disp(c(1:5));pause(.5)end
```

Saved two bytes thanks to Tom Carpenter! Using a single string instead of two strings in a cell array was shorter.

**Explanation:**

```
c='--:--00:21';  % A string where the 5 first characters are --:-- or 12:00 when reversed
while c=flip(c)  % A string is always considered true in Octave, so this will loop forever
                 % while flipping the order of the string each time
 disp(c(1:5)     % display the 5 first characters of the string c
 pause(.5)       % Pause 0.5 second
end              % End loop
```

A few bytes saved because Octave doesn't require a colon or semicolon between `flip(c)` and `disp()`, and between `pause(.5)` and `end`.

Comment: Nice idea to use `flip` instead of a counter!

Answer (score 15):

## Python2, <s>80</s> <s>75</s> <s>73</s> <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```
import time
n=0
while[time.sleep(.5)]:print"1-2-::0-0-"[n::2];n^=1
```

<s>I noticed that my string magic got a little longer than picking the string from an array.</s> Nevermind, figured it out.

**Explanation**:

- I set a counter **n** to 0, which will be toggled between 0 and 1.
- I loop endlessly with the loop `while 1`.
- I create a string `1-2-::0-0-`, which contains the string `12:00` and `--:--` interlapped.

  - Starting from the index 0 with a step of 2, we get: `12:00`
  - Starting from the index 1 with a step of 2, we get: `--:--`
- I use **n** to make the repeated sequence **0**, **1**, **0**, **1**, **0**... which will be the starting index of the string.

  - Using `n^=1`, in each loop, we get that sequence. `^` being the XOR-operator.
  - If **n** == 0 --> `n^=1` results in 1
  - If **n** == 1 --> `n^=1` results in 0
- I print the string, and sleep (`.5` -> `0.5`) seconds.

[@FlipTack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60919/fliptack) saved 4 bytes! --> Put the loop in one line.

[@Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod) saved 2 bytes! --> `n+=1` to `n^=1`, thus `n%2` to `n`.

[@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) saved a byte! --> `while 1` --> `while[time.sleep(.5)]`.

Comment: you can replace `n+=1` with `n^=1`, and then use `[n::2]`, saves 2 bytes and avoid big numbers c:

Comment: if you change the `print"1-2-::0-0-"[n::2]` to `print"\b"*6+"1-2-::0-0-"[n::2],` it will add a few bytes but it will blink in place

Comment: @Buzz you can use `\r` instead of `\b\b\b...` to move to the beginning of the line. But anyway, this would only add bytes onto the current solution.

Comment: You can save a byte by doing `while[time.sleep(.5)]:`.

Comment: @xnor I was so sure, that this couldn't be golfed more. This site continues to amaze me. Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing as @FlipTack but had to add `sys.stdout.flush()`. Does someone have it working without?

Answer (score 11):

#### bash, <s>58 56 45</s> 41 bytes

New version 2022, (not very system friendly), but...

```
bash <(yes "read -t.5 -p"{--:--,12:00}\;)
```

or with *newline*: 45

```
bash <(yes "read -t.5 -p'
"{--:--,12:00}"';")
```

or with *carrier return*: 47

```
bash <(yes "read -t.5 -p$'\r"{--:--,12:00}"';")
```

<s>saved 3 byte by suppressing `--` after `set` as 1st arg is a number.</s>

```
set 12:00 --:--;for((a=1;;a=3-a)){ echo ${!a};sleep .5;}
```

Saved 16 byte by using [@DigitalTrauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/256376?noredirect=1)'s syntax:

```
f()(echo $1;sleep .5);f 12:00;f --:--;exec $0
```

Then loosing 5 bytes because of [zeppelin's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/256462?noredirect=1).

This could not be tested on command line. As we involve `$0`, this must be written into a script to run.

#### Divert

With a little preparation, this could become nice (**412 bytes**):

```
set -- "         ▗▖         
▗▄▄▖▗▄▄▖ ▝▘ ▗▄▄▖▗▄▄▖
         ▗▖         
         ▝▘         " " ▟▌ ▟▀▜▖ ▗▖ ▗▛▙ ▗▛▙ 
 ▐▌  ▗▟▘ ▝▘ █▗▐▌█▗▐▌
 ▐▌ ▗▛▗▖ ▗▖ ▜▖▟▘▜▖▟▘
▝▀▀▘▀▀▀▘ ▝▘  ▀▘  ▀▘ "
r=`tput cup 0`
clear;for((a=1;;a=3-a)){ printf "$r${!a}";sleep .5;}
```

Or even same two lines but with:

```
set -- '                                            






      HM!          .o#HMMMMM#o.                 .o#MMMMH#\\         .d#MMMMH#\\
    _HMMi         ?MMH*"""`"MMMb               dMMH"""`*MMH,      dMMH"""`*MMH.
##HMMMMMi        |MMP"       9MML             ?MMP      `MMM.    dMM?      `MMM.
`""`"9MM|        dMM!        -MMR     HMH}   .MMM        |MM}   .MMH        |MM|
     |MM|         "`         JMMT     dHH}   |MM|         MMM   |MM|        -MMM
     |MM!                 .,HMM*             |MM|         MMM.  ]MM|         MMM
     |MMi              _o#MMH*"              |MM|         MMM   {MM|         MMM
     |MMi           .dHMM#""                 |MM|         MMM"  {MM|        .MMM
     |MMi         .HMM*"                     `MM6        ,MMR   |MM}        |MMF
     |MMi        ,MMP"                        9MM,       dMM|    HMM,       dMM"
     {MMi        MMM?\\o,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\,     q##+    `HMM\\    .dMM?     `HMH\\    .dMM?
     |MM|       :MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM[     HMMk     `*HMM##MMM#"       `*HMM##MMMP"
      "`          "     ` ` ` `                   """"`""            """"""    ' '






                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                      MHM|                                      
                                      HHH|                                      
                                                                                
               ______.  ._______.            ________.  ._______.               
               MMMMMM:  {MMMMMMM|            &MMMMMMM:  |MMMMMMM[               
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                      ###|                                      
                                      MMM|                                      
                                                                               '
```

Comment: `s(){ echo $1;sleep .5;};for((;;)){ s 12:00;s --:--;}`

Comment: @manatwork Nice! I think it's not same script! You have to publish them as an answer!

Comment: I gotta admit, that ASCII art is absolutely gorgeous... Did you use a tool to create it, or did you make it by hand?

Comment: @ETHproductions I use *Ghostscript*: `printf '%%\041\n/Helvetica findfont\n24 scalefont\nsetfont\nnewpath\n%s %s moveto\n(%s) show\nshowpage\n' -2.456 0.550003 12:00 | gs -sDEVICE=pnmraw -r600 -g470x146 -sOutputFile=- -q - | pnmscale -width 160 | ppmtopgm | pgmtopbm | pbmtoascii -2x4` ;-)

Comment: ...or `f()(echo $1;sleep .5);f 12:00;f --:--;$0`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Well! Shorted than manatwork's one! Same remark; you have to publish you own answer!

Comment: With $0 your program will keep allocating resources and will fail eventually (i.e. this is not  an _infinite_ loop). You can probably replace it with _exec $0_ to make each iteration reuse the same process.

Comment: @zeppelin Usualy, I upvote comments who made me make an edit, but, for your last comment, I will make such an exception. Sorry ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri Ha ha :) Anyway, it all looks good now, so you got my +1.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma new version: `bash <(yes "read -t.5 -p"{--:--,12:00}\;)`

Answer (score 11):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @nmjcman101 by swapping the order of `12:00` and `--:--` so that `k` can be removed any by removing `ò` so that it could be added implicitly at the end*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @DJMcMayhem by putting both `12:00` and `--:--` in one line*

```
i12:00--:--<ESC>bDòVp:sl500m
```

Old Solution:

```
i12:00<ESC>ò:sl500m
Óä/-
:sl500m
uò
```

`<ESC>` is `0x1b`

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 6931 323a 3030 2d2d 3a2d 2d1b 6244 f256  i12:00--:--.bD.V
00000010: 703a 736c 3530 306d                      p:sl500m
```

#### Explanation

```
i12:00--:--<ESC>   inserts 12:00\n--:--
bD                 go to the beginning of --:-- and delete it
ò                  recursively do:
 Vp                 select line and paste (effectively doing a replace)
 :sl500m            sleep for 500 milliseconds
                   the last ò is added implicitly at the end
```

#### Gif (outdated)

**Note:** I have highlighting turned on

[image: giff]

Comment: You took _blinking_ literally in that gif :-)

Comment: The second `ò` is given implicitly, so you can remove it.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem It, for some reason, doesn't work without the second `ò`. It only runs once

Comment: `@:` probably tries to repeat the substitution, as that uses `:s` under the covers.

Comment: Swap the order of your inputs so you don't need the first `k`.  Then instead of `pkdd` you can just use `Vp`, as `p` in visual select mode effectively swaps the selection with the default register.

Comment: @nmjcman101 Thanks for the tip, TIL about `V` :)

Comment: I know you have problems removing the `ò`, but if that works now, I think you should be able to change it to `òVp:sl500m` and let V add the `^Mò` for 2 bytes.

Comment: @nmjcman101 Aah, I didn't know that `^M` is added along with `ò`. Thanks again for the tip :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yup, V adds a *lot* of things implicitly. `^M`, `<esc>` and `ò` or `ñ` are all added implicitly, and you can also end any operator implicitly. (for example, `d` at the end of a program, macro, or global command will delete a line)

Comment: You could do `i12:00--:--<esc>bDòVp:sl500m` to save one more byte.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I was thinking about putting them in one line, but didn't know of a 1-byte command to go to the middle. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript, 59 bytes

```js
y=1;setInterval('console.log(["12:00","--:--"][y^=1])',500)
```

**Explanation**

`setInterval('...',500)` sets an interval to execute code in the string every 500 milliseconds, or 1/2 a second.

`y=1` sets a variable, `y`, to 1 initially. That way, the first thing that is printed is `12:00` because `y` is used to access the array.

`console.log(...)` logs whatever to the console, in this either `12:00` or `--:--`.

`["12:00","--:--"][y^=1]` creates an array with strings containing both states. Then, `y` is used to access one of elements. Finally, `^=`, or XOR compound operator does `y = y ^ 1`. This just inverts the bit because `1 ^ 1` is 0, and `0 ^ 1` is 1, similar to what [@TuukkaX did](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105325/56456). This way, the string logged alternates between the two elements in the array and thus creates the blinking effect.

Comment: Was able to save a byte with this: `y=1;setInterval('console.log(y?"12:00":"--:--");y=!y',500)`

Comment: ETHproductions tip at my answer: `You can save some bytes with setInterval(...,i=500) :-)`. We basically have the same answer and it works for yours, too.

Answer (score 9):

### Perl, 49 bytes

```pl
{select$,,$,,$,,0.5;say$|--?"12:00":"--:--";redo}
```

Perl's `sleep` can't sleep for duration bellow 1 sec, hence the use of `select undef, undef, undef, .5` (golfed by replacing `undef` with `$,`) to sleep .5 second.
Other interesting thing: `$|` can only hold `0` or `1`. So `$|--` just toggles its value, from `0` to `1`.
And finally, `{... ;redo}` acts like an infinite loop.

Comment: You can cut two bytes using `while` instead of `redo`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784NSc1uURFRweCDPRMyzMyc1IVihMrVWp0de2VDI2sDAyUrJR0da10dZX@//@XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNAAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), 16 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
--:-- 12:00ḷçėḍh
```

*Noodel* is still very much a work in progress. Just trying to get my feet wet with a couple of challenges.

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=--%3A--%2012%3A00%E1%B8%B7%C3%A7%C4%97%E1%B8%8Dh&input=&run=true)

#### How It Works

```
--:--            # Creates the string literal "--:--" and places i into the front of the pipe.
                 # Space is a NOP command to separate the string literals.
      12:00      # Creates the string literal "12:00" and places it into the front of the pipe.
           ḷ     # Loop the following code unconditionally.
            ç    # Clear the screen and print a copy of what is in the pipe.
             ė   # Take what is in the front of the pipe and put it into the back.
              ḍh # Delay for half a second.
```

---

Here is a code snippet:)

```html
<div id="noodel" code="--:-- 12:00ḷçėḍh" input="" cols="10" rows="2"></div>

<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/noodel-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain the encoding? It adds up to much more than 16 in UTF-8.

Comment: @devRicher I made my own [code page](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html) to get closer to how I wanted the language to work. Do I need to say something about it? Sorry, I am new:)

Comment: I looked at your link, it doesnt explain the encoding. You see, not all characters are 1 byte by "default" (UTF-8). Specify an existing encoding or make one, elsewise this is a wrong byte count. There should be a meta post somewhere about this. Unless you define an encoding, this is UTF-8 and is 22 bytes. @tkellehe

Comment: @devRicher Thank you, I will look into it:)

Comment: Found the [meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5878/what-character-encodings-may-a-submission-use), btw.

Comment: @devRicher What would be the best way to indicate in the answer that it uses its own code page? Similar to that of Jelly or APL?

Answer (score 6):

## [*><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
<v":1200----"
S>@5dov>~r@@}r5
1&}o:&<^!?:-
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=DwNwRAXAjATADHAtMxYBQBlAfAAQKwAmA9iFgH4BOOOAvhXmlAGQ1ERPAB6AhAPwSIgA)

I feel like I should be able to make this shorter, I have a couple ideas to try ... Basically this makes a stack of `:1200----`. It isolates the `:` and flips the stack, inserting the `:` in the middle of either `----` or `1200` (depending on whichever is at the end of the stack).

I should also note that the only *><> instruction this uses is `S` (sleep), otherwise this is a proper ><> program.

Update: Saved 1 byte by shifting the `:` to the right instead of protecting it with a register.

### Explanation

#### Initialisation

```
<v":1200----"
```

Here we build the stack we'll be using for the life of the program.

```
<              move the IP left
  ":1200----"  push ":1200----" to the stack
 v             move the IP down into "output time"
```

#### Output time

```
 >@5dov
1&}o:&<^!?:-
```

This is the section where the time is actually outputted. First 5 is pushed to the stack so the loop below knows to run 5 times.

```
Initialisation:

 >@5dov

 >       move the IP right
  @      move the ":" back two spaces in the stack
   5     push 5 to the stack (let's call this `i`)
    do   output carriage return
      v  move IP down into "loop"

Loop:

1&}o:&<^!?:-

      <       move the IP left
     &        place i onto the register
  }o:         output a character and shift the stack left
 &            place i back onto the stack
1          -  decrement i by 1
       ^!?:   if i == 0, exit to "recover and swap"
```

#### Recover and swap

```
S      >~r@@}r5
```

Here we recover the `:` from the position it results in after the output, and we end up with a reversed stack. This actually exits into "output time" nicely, causing an infinite loop.

```
       >         move the IP right
        ~        remove trailing i from stack
         r@@     reverse the stack and move ":" to the front
            }r   reverse the stack again, keeping ":" on the front
S             5  sleep for 500ms
```

---

#### 45 byte solution

```
<v[5"12:00"1
d/S5
o/!?l
v>]?v
 00.>0"--:--"5[
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=DwNw2grARAjATALgAxNgKACYHoDKE0D2WAhAPwA2aIAfALqkhoAEKAdNagLScLdQRggA)

This one is also basically a ><> program.

I really thought it'd be able to save some bytes with this approach. This quite simply outputs `12:00`, then `--:--`. I save bytes by reusing the output routine `o/!?l` (I even reuse that mirror as both entry and exit). I utilise multiple stacks to store the state (has output `12` or `--`), and select which state I should output with `v>]?v`.

<sup>Explanations coming soon! (1/2)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

### HTML/CSS (Chrome only), 80 + 4 = 84 bytes

```css
tt:after{content:"--:--";animation:a 1s infinite}@keyframes a{to{content:"12:00"
```

```html
<tt>
```

**Edit**: The "content" attribute is not *animatable* by the [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css), but is on Chrome desktop browser.

Comment: Seems to be Chrome specific. At least not works on Firefox. This is not a problem, the solution is still valid, just would be nice to specify it.

Answer (score 5):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```
{sleep 01?@12:00`┘sleep 01?@--:--
```

QBasic unfortunately can only sleep for whole seconds. I'll see about devising a method to allow for more flexibility soon. I've input 1 as `01` to simulate `.5`.

Explanation:

```
{         Starts DO loop
sleep 01  Sleeps for 1 second
?@12:00`  Creates A$, sets value to "12:00" and prints A$
┘         Newline: a string literal doesn't break the line, so we need a newline to 
          control the compiled QBasic syntax
          <Rinse and repeat for "--:--">
          <DO-LOOP implicitly closed by QBIC>
```

In older builds of QBIC, `$` and    (space) were reserved characters. Calling a QBasic function that needed spaces (like `sleep x`) or `$` (`left$(..)`) required a code literal:

```
'QBASIC CODE`
```

Code in a code literal block is passed directly to QBasic without being parsed by QBIC. By offloading functions from those symbols (`$` became `'`, and newlines are now `┘` (alt-217) instead of  ) the symbols are no longer seen by QBIC as special chars and simply passed on. The same is effectively true for the lowercase alphabet: it's used to represent numeric variables in both QBIC and QBasic and are left unchanged. Using QBasic functionality that is not implemented in QBIC (like `SLEEP`) is therefor simply a matter of not using QBIC reserved chars. This is made easier with the recent changes in the command symbols.

Answer (score 5):

## [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language), 100 bytes (Non-Competing)

**Code:**

```
ht point fontsize 99 repeat [ cs sleep 500 if repcount % 2 [ label '12:00' ] else [ label '--:--' ]]
```

**Explanation:**

```
ht                            ; Hide Turtle (Unnecessary... Added for visual clarity)
point                         ; Draw a point with size and color of the pen
fontsize 99                   ; Font Size = 99 pt (Unnecessary... Added for visual clarity)
repeat [                      ; Endless Loop
    cs                        ; Clear Screen
    sleep 500                 ; Wait for 500 ms
    if repcount % 2 [         ; If the Repetition Count is Even...
        label '12:00'         ; Draw '12:00'
    ]
    else [                    ; Otherwise...
        label '--:--'         ; Draw '--:--'
    ]
]
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 72 bytes

```
setInterval('l=console.log,l("12:00"),setTimeout("l(`--:--`)",‌​500)',1e3)
```

Thanks to Kritixi Lithos for 1 byte and L. Serne for 4 bytes!

Comment: `1000` can be shortened to `1e3`

Comment: `setInterval` and `setTimeout` accept a string with code as a first argument, so you can save another 4B: `setInterval('l=console.log,l("12:00"),setTimeout("l(`--:--`)",500)',1e3)`

Comment: The `\``s mean this is now ES6, whereas the previous answer only needed ES5.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <del>88</del> <del>85</del> <del>73</del> 71 bytes

```py
import time
c="--:--00:21"
while 1:print c[:5];c=c[::-1];time.sleep(.5)
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/EzQ6/2)

By borrowing [Stewie Griffin's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105324/36594) of flipping the list, the program was made possible. Ungolfed version with explanation:

```
import time                      # Import time module
c = "--:--00:21"                 # String with two values
while 1:                         # Infinite Loop
    print c[::5]                 # Print the first 5 chars in string
    c = c[::-1]                  # Flip the string
    time.sleep(.5)               # Wait 0.5 seconds
```

Thanks @FlipTack for saving 14 bytes!

Comment: You can golf it even shorter using string slicing, [like this](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ZW5BfVKJQkpmbypVsq6Sra6Wra2BgZWSoxFWekZmTqmBoVVCUmVeikBxtZRprnWwLpK10DWOtQTr0inNSUws09Ew1//8HAA)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <strike>51 50</strike> 47

```
for(;;usleep(5e5))echo$i++%2?"--:--
":"12:00
";
```

1 byte saved due to manatwork and another 3 saved by insertusernamehere. Thanks!

Comment: If you move the `usleep(5e5)` call to `for`'s 3rd parameter, the `,` separator becomes unnecessary, saving 1 character.

Comment: @manatwork thanks ! I had `while(1)` at first.

Comment: You can save *3 more bytes*: Remove the white space between `echo` and `$i` and replace `\n` with an actual newline.

Comment: @insertusernamehere even at golfing this hurts my eyes :D but hey it works.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyth, 23 bytes

```
#?=!Z"12:00""--:--".d.5
```

In pseudocode:

```
                Z = 0
#               while 1:
 ?=!Z               if ( Z = not Z ):
     "12:00"            print("12:00")
                    else:
     "--:--"            print("--:--")
 .d.5               sleep(0.5)
```

Uses preinitialized variable `Z` as the flip-flop, and inverts its state every time `if` tries to check the condition.

Comment: put .d5 in the front of the loop and remove the end quote

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
Dynamic@If[Clock[]>.5,"12:00","--:--"]
```

**Explanation**

```
Clock[]
```

Outputs a clock variable that cycles continuously from 0 to 1 every second.

```
If[Clock[]>.5,"12:00","--:--"]
```

If the clock variable is greater than .5, output "12:00." If not, output "--:--".

```
Dynamic@ ...
```

Make the program dynamic (constantly updating)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>48 41</s>  34 bytes

```perl6
loop {print "\r",<--:-- 12:00>[$_=!$_];sleep .5}
```

```perl6
loop {put <--:-- 12:00>[$_=!$_];sleep .5}
```

```perl6
sleep .put/2 for |<12:00 --:-->xx*
```

Comment: using a `for` loop can make it a little shorter: `for |<12:00 --:-->xx* {sleep .5;.say}`

Comment: Even shorter if you make use of the fact that `say` returns 1: `sleep .say/2 for |<12:00 --:-->xx*`

Answer (score 3):

## GNU sed, 39 bytes

EDITS:

- Swapped *sleep* and *i12:00* (to make source code look a bit nicer)

**Golfed**

```
s/^/sleep .5/
h
i12:00
e
i--:--
x
e
G
D
```

**Explained**

```
s/^/sleep .5/   #Put 'sleep .5' to the pattern space
h               #Copy pattern space to hold space
i12:00          #Print "12:00" (insert before a line) 
e               #Execute command that is found in pattern space
i--:--          #Print "--:--"
x               #Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces
e               #Execute command that is found in pattern space

G               #Append a newline to the contents of the pattern 
                #space, and then append the contents of the hold
                #space to that of the pattern space.

D               #Delete text in the pattern space up to the 
                #first newline, and restart cycle with the 
                #resultant pattern space, without reading a new 
                #line of input.
```

[Try It Online !](https://goo.gl/4al8TH)

Answer (score 3):

## dc (bash), 37 bytes

```
[12:00][--:--][[rp!sleep .5]xlax]dsax
```

This works by pushing the two strings "12:00" and "--:--" on the stack and then repeatedly swapping the values, printing the item at the top of the stack, and sleeping half a second.

To run this, you can save it in a file and then type

> dc *filename*

or you can run it directly from the bash command line by typing

> dc <<<'[12:00][--:--][[rp!sleep .5]xlax]dsax'

Answer (score 3):

### ruby, <strike>47</strike> 42 bytes

No ruby answer yet, so here is my first try:

```
%w{12:00 --:--}.cycle{|a|puts a;sleep 0.5}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 32 keystrokes

```
qq:sl500m<CR>S12:00<Esc>:<UP><CR>S--:--<Esc>@qq@q
```

Answer (score 3):

## **Python 3, 75 bytes**

```
import time
x=['12:00','--:--']
for i in x:x+=[i];print(i);time.sleep(.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 22 bytes

```
®‘©ị“12:00“--:--”ṄœS.ß
```

Doesn't work on TIO. Getting Jelly to run on Android with QPython3 was also a fun experience.

#### Explanation

```
®‘©ị“12:00“--:--”ṄœS.ß    Main link. No arguments. 
®                         Read the register. Initially 0.
 ‘                        Increment. 
  ©                       Save to the register.
   ị                      Get the n'th (wrapping) item of...
    “12:00“--:--”         ["12:00", "--:--"]
                 Ṅ        Print the string and a newline. 
                  œS      Sleep for...
                    .     ...0.5 seconds. (. is an alias for 0.5)
                     ß    Call this link again.
```

Comment: Does this sleep? Can you add an explanation?

Comment: @steenbergh Added. Sorry for the delay, editing those indents for the explanation is a bit hard on the SE app with a non-monospace font.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <strike>57</strike> 55

```
setInterval('console.log(++i%2?"12:00":"--:--")',i=500)
```

2 bytes saved thanks to ETHproductions

Comment: You can save some bytes with `setInterval(...,i=500)` :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (in browser), <s>174</s> <s>160</s> <s>159</s> <s>122</s> <s>112</s> <s>111</s> <s>109</s> <s>107</s> 66 (91) bytes

I've taked of `pre` because using monotyped font is not part of requirement, so my new count is **66**. Some chars are added to use monospaced font but as this is not needed, I won't count this **25** more chars.

Thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) for saving 14 bytes,

to [Kritixi Lithos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/kritixi-lithos) for saving 1 byte,

to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for saving <s>1</s> **3** byte,

to [Christoph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29637/christoph) for saving two more bytes and

to myself for saving 37 bytes by using `[..][b^=1]` instead of `setTimeout`... and 10 more by replacing `function(){..}` by double-quotes...

```js
setInterval("document.body.innerHTML=++b%2?'12:00':'--:--'",b=500)
```

```css
body{font-family:Courier}
```

... worse:

### From 66 to *something more*...

... but for fun, in the spirit of a blinking display:

```js
SVG="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";XLNK="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
s=["1200","----"];p=0;function d(n){for(i=n.length;i>0;i--) {
  document.getElementById('n'+i).setAttribute('class','n'+n[i-1])}
  document.getElementById('sz').setAttribute('class','n'+n[0])}
setInterval("p=1-p;d(s[p])",500);
```

```css
#svg2 { --c: #FF6;stroke:#432;stroke-width:12;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none; } path.b { fill:#543;stroke:none; } .blue     { --c: #68F; } .green    { --c: #6F8; } .red      { --c: #F88; } .dec rect  { stroke: var(--c); } .n1 #B { stroke: var(--c); }  .n1 #C { stroke: var(--c); } .n2 #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .n2 #B { stroke: var(--c); } .n2 #D { stroke: var(--c); }  .n2 #E { stroke: var(--c); } .n2 #G { stroke: var(--c); }  .n3 #A { stroke: var(--c); } .n3 #B { stroke: var(--c); }  .n3 #C { stroke: var(--c); } .n3 #D { stroke: var(--c); }  .n3 #G { stroke: var(--c); } .n4 #B { stroke: var(--c); }  .n4 #C { stroke: var(--c); } .n4 #F { stroke: var(--c); }  .n4 #G { stroke: var(--c); } .n5 #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .n5 #C { stroke: var(--c); } .n5 #D { stroke: var(--c); }  .n5 #F { stroke: var(--c); } .n5 #G { stroke: var(--c); } .n6 #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .n6 #C { stroke: var(--c); } .n6 #D { stroke: var(--c); }  .n6 #E { stroke: var(--c); } .n6 #F { stroke: var(--c); }  .n6 #G { stroke: var(--c); } .n7 #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .n7 #B { stroke: var(--c); } .n7 #C { stroke: var(--c); } .n8 #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .n8 #B { stroke: var(--c); } .n8 #C { stroke: var(--c); }  .n8 #D { stroke: var(--c); } .n8 #E { stroke: var(--c); }  .n8 #F { stroke: var(--c); } .n8 #G { stroke: var(--c); } .n9 #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .n9 #B { stroke: var(--c); } .n9 #C { stroke: var(--c); }  .n9 #D { stroke: var(--c); } .n9 #F { stroke: var(--c); }  .n9 #G { stroke: var(--c); } .n0 #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .n0 #B { stroke: var(--c); } .n0 #C { stroke: var(--c); }  .n0 #D { stroke: var(--c); } .n0 #E { stroke: var(--c); }  .n0 #F { stroke: var(--c); } .n11 #B { stroke: var(--c); } .n11 #C { stroke: var(--c); } .n11 #E { stroke: var(--c); } .n11 #F { stroke: var(--c); } .nA #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .nA #B { stroke: var(--c); } .nA #C { stroke: var(--c); }  .nA #E { stroke: var(--c); } .nA #F { stroke: var(--c); }  .nA #G { stroke: var(--c); } .nB #C { stroke: var(--c); }  .nB #D { stroke: var(--c); } .nB #E { stroke: var(--c); }  .nB #F { stroke: var(--c); } .nB #G { stroke: var(--c); } .nC #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .nC #D { stroke: var(--c); } .nC #E { stroke: var(--c); }  .nC #F { stroke: var(--c); } .nD #B { stroke: var(--c); }  .nD #C { stroke: var(--c); } .nD #D { stroke: var(--c); }  .nD #E { stroke: var(--c); } .nD #G { stroke: var(--c); } .nE #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .nE #D { stroke: var(--c); } .nE #E { stroke: var(--c); }  .nE #F { stroke: var(--c); } .nE #G { stroke: var(--c); } .nF #A { stroke: var(--c); }  .nF #E { stroke: var(--c); } .nF #F { stroke: var(--c); }  .nF #G { stroke: var(--c); } .nR #E { stroke: var(--c); }  .nR #G { stroke: var(--c); } .nO #C { stroke: var(--c); }  .nO #D { stroke: var(--c); } .nO #E { stroke: var(--c); }  .nO #G { stroke: var(--c); } .n- #G { stroke: var(--c); }  .n1 #y { stroke: var(--c); } .n1 #z { stroke: var(--c); }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 645 230" id="svg2"> <defs id="dfs4"><g id="n"><path d="M 15,5 155,5 145,225 5,225 z" class="b"/> <path id="A" d="M 45,15 125, 15"/><path id="B" d="M 135,25 125,105"/><path id="C" d="M 125,125 115,205"/><path id="D" d="M 25,215 105,215"/><path id="E" d="M 25,125 15,205"/><path id="F" d="M 35,25 25,105"/><path id="G" d="M 35,115 115,115"/><rect id="P" width="5" height="5" ry="2.5" x="130" y="205"/></g><g id="s"><path d="M 10,5 35,5 25,225 0,225 z" id="a" class="b"/><rect id="y" width="5" height="5" ry="2.5" x="13.5" y="145"/><rect id="z" width="5" x="17" height="5" ry="2.5" y="75"/></g></defs><use id="n1" xlink:href="#n" /><use id="n2" xlink:href="#n" transform="translate(150,0)" /><use xlink:href="#s" id="sz" transform="translate(305,0)"/><use id="n3" transform="translate(335,0)" xlink:href="#n" /><use id="n4" xlink:href="#n" transform="translate(485,0)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: `1000` can become `1e3`

Comment: You can save a bunch of bytes by removing all instances of `window.`; `window.setTimeout` is the same as `setTimeout`.

Comment: `tt` is shorter than `pre` and also implies the use of monospace font. (Just it is inline element, not block, but this should make no difference here.) `b=document.body.append(a=document.createElement('tt'))`

Comment: `d=document;d.body.append(a=d.createElement('tt'));setInterval("a.innerHTML=++b%2?'12:00':'--:--'",b=500)` saves 5 bytes

Comment: Is there a reason to generate an element? `setInterval("document.body.innerHTML=++b%2?'12:00':'--:--'",b=500)` only lags the fancy monospace but is only 66 bytes.

Comment: @Christoph anyway using `body` and add *style* for body to `Courier` still save 16 characters, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Postscript <s>225</s> 214

For fun only! Don't send this to a real printer!!

```
/Courier findfont 9 scalefont setfont{usertime 500 mod 5 lt{newpath 9 9 moveto 1 setgray 99 setlinewidth 99 99 lineto stroke 0 setgray}if newpath 9 9 moveto usertime 999 mod 500 lt{(--:--)}{(12:00)}ifelse show}loop
```

Try it:

```
gs -c '/Courier findfont 9 scalefont setfont{usertime 500 mod 5 lt{newpath 9 9 moveto 1 setgray 99 setlinewidth 99 99 lineto stroke 0 setgray}if newpath 9 9 moveto usertime 999 mod 500 lt{(--:--)}{(12:00)}ifelse show}loop'
```

or

```
cat <<eops >/tmp/blinkingTwelve.ps
%!
/Courier findfont
9 scalefont
setfont
{
  usertime 500 mod 5 lt {
    newpath
    9 9 moveto
    1 setgray
    99 setlinewidth
    99 99 lineto
    stroke
    0 setgray
  } if
  newpath
  9 9 moveto
  usertime 999 mod 500 lt {
    (--:--)
  } {
    (12:00)
  } ifelse
  show
} loop
eops
```

then

```
gs /tmp/blinkingTwelve.ps
gv /tmp/blinkingTwelve.ps
```

But **don't try to open this** with more sophisticated viewer and **care about desktop thumbnailer**!

Comment: If `gs -c '...'` command prompt a white page, you may have to grow the display window or use a smaller resolution: `gs -r45 -c '...'` or smaller papersize `gs -r600 -g360x200 -c '...'`

Answer (score 2):

### QBasic (QB64) <s>55</s> 53 Bytes

```
A$="12:00
B$="--:--
DO
?A$
_DELAY .5
SWAP A$,B$
LOOP
```

Saved 2 bytes as newline appears to terminate the string definitions.

SWAP makes all the difference.  For vanilla QBASIC replace `_DELAY` with `SLEEP S` where `S` is an integer in seconds, but then the frequency is wrong.

Comment: Disappointingly replacing `DO..LOOP` with `1..GOTO 1` results in the same byte count

Answer (score 2):

## Q/KDB+, 61 Bytes

```
s:("12:00";"--:--")
b:1b
.z.ts:{b::not b;show s[b]}
\t 500
```

Explanation:

```
s:("12:00";"--:--")
```

Assign the values we wish to show in a list.

```
b:1b
```

Assign a boolean variable to flip between 0 and 1 easily.

```
.z.ts:{b::not b;show s[b]}
```

This is a KDB+ function which is invoked in set intervals by the timer function (\t) http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/dotzdotts

 This executes the code inside the curly braces when \t is set. Show the value in s and then flipping the value of b between 0 and 1.

```
\t 500
```

Effectively calls .z.ts every 500ms.

Answer (score 2):

## Windows PowerShell, <del>46</del> 55 bytes

```
function a{sleep -m 500;cls};for(){"12:00";a;"--:--";a}
```

#### Original Code:

```
a{sleep -m 500;cls};for(){"12:00";a;"--:--";a}
^ this won't work on other PCs. No idea why.
```

Answer (score 2):

### [QuickBASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickBASIC), 167 bites (yummy)

```
a%=VAL(RIGHT$(STR$(TIMER*100),2))
b%=a%+50
IF b%>99THEN b%=b%-99
DO
c%=VAL(RIGHT$(STR$(TIMER*100),2))
IF c%=a% THEN PRINT"--:--"
IF c%=b% THEN PRINT"12:00"
LOOP
```

I was never going to win anyways. QB doesn't have a floor(), and also doesn't have a function to sleep for *x* milliseconds. Therefore, this works by grabbing the floating point portion of the TIMER (returns seconds elapsed since midnight, plus a fraction of the current second expressed as a two-digit decimal). We then add a loop-around "50 units" to it to determine when the phase should switch from "--:--" to "12:00", and use the original TIMER decimal for the switch from "12:00" to "--:--".

Finally, even running this complied in QB4.5, in DOSBox on a rather powerful machine will skip beats. That's because QB really isn't fast enough to perform the DO-LOOP and evaluations inside of the MS we're doing the comparison in. Would need a box from the FUTURE!

Anyway, I now look 100, and I made every American University student happy since they probably have an answer for their Comp Sci class -- since they're still teaching this...

Comment: Can you remove some of the spaces? i.e `b% = b% - 99` to `b%=b%-99`?

Comment: Yea I'm pretty sure I could, but I used the original IDE which, after you hit enter at the end of the line, would add them back in. I'd have to edit it outside of the IDE in DOS, and then figureout the parameters for the linker/compiler to check if my solution still worked... So it can be shorter, but not within my frame of effort.

Comment: Well, you need to golf this code or else it's not a valid answer and will be deleted.  Sorry about that. (I completely understand what you mean, but the community as a whole has decided against non-golfed answers)

Comment: Good point, I'll remove the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <s>79</s> 62 bytes

### V2

-17 bytes by changing from an awful indexing loop to looping over an infinite list.

Creates an infinite list of `"12:00"` and `"--:--"` repeating over and over again, then uses `doseq` to constantly pull the next message, and print it.

```clj
(doseq[m(cycle["12:00""--:--"])](Thread/sleep 500)(println m))
```

### V1

```clj
(loop[i 0](Thread/sleep 500)(println(["12:00""--:--"]i))(recur(if(= 0 i)1 0))))
```

I couldn't think of a good way to compact the "12:00" and "--:--" constants, so I had to just hard code them.

Ungolfed:

```clj
(loop [i 0] ; Track which sign we showed last
    (Thread/sleep 500)
    (println (["12:00" "--:--"] i)) ; Index the vector to get the string to print
    (recur (if (= 0 i)1 0))) ; Swap the index, and loop again
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 22 bytes (non-competing)

```
`--:`wO`12:0`&["500oWF
```

This answer makes use of the two stacks, by flipping between them, printing the characters in turn:

```
`--:`    \ Push these characters to stack 1
 w       \ Mirror around center, yielding "--:--"
 O       \ On the second stack...
 `12:0`  \ Push these characters
 &       \ Duplicate the last (for :00)

 [        \ Infinitely:
  "       \   Print the current stack
  500oW   \   Wait 500 milliseconds
  F       \   Swap stacks
          \ (Implicit end loop)
```

The `oW` command is part of a set of experimental commands that postdate the challenge, making this answer non-competing.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>46</s> 45 bytes

*-1 byte, thanks @AdmBorkBork*

```powershell
for(){('12:00','--:--')[$i++%2]
sleep -m 500}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `;` in the `for` loop. [Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59429/42963).

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>138</s> <s>131</s> 127 bytes

```cs
class H{static int Main(){for(int n=1;;System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500))System.Console.WriteLine((n^=1)>0?"--:--":"12:00");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxCwIhFMDxr3I46aBo0KJcDS0NNV3QFoi96oE9w@cSx312I7jt/4N/Yp1Khd5TjszDceYWG6YBqQ3niCTV/ChV/kmjC2H6coO3ubwqxDvScy0zZYCP3Fqr1LocCnHJYK4VG5yQQEq6jU7t7F5o7bUWXriNt1aosCy9/wA)

Simple one-liner code.

---

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 127 bytes

```cs
class H{static int Main(){for(int n=1;;System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500))System.Console.Write((n^=1)>0?"\r--:--":"\r12:00");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxCwIhGIDhvyJOOigatChXQ0tL0wUtEYh9leB9hp9LHPfbreC254U3koqlQu8xByJ2nKmFliJL2NgpJBRyfpQq/omD9X78UINJn18Vwj3hc5UeM8BbbI2Rcl0OBalk0JeaGgiBt8HKndnza1XKKcXdT3bjjOHSL0vvXw)

This code has same length with the code above, it does replace previous line.

---

-7 bytes by using for loops.
-4 bytes by using ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>152</s> 151 bytes (Thanks @AlexRacer)

```
public class c{public static void main(String[] a)throws Exception{int i=1;while(i>0){System.out.println(i++%2<1?"--:--":"12:00");Thread.sleep(500);}}}
```

[Try it here!](http://www.browxy.com/) * (this compiler prints only once a second, couldn't find a better one)

Comment: Change `while` loop to `for(int i=0;;){...}` and also `i++%2==1` to `i++%2<1`

Comment: Changed this part (i++%2==1), but kept the while. Using your suggestion would even lose some bytes. Thanks for the feedback ;)

Comment: You can save a few bytes by limiting this to a function, not a whole program (which is allowed): `void f()throws Exception{ ... }`

Comment: @Snowman oh, thanks for the advice! Next time I'll try use only the function then.

Comment: You can remove `public ` in front of `class` (-7 bytes); remove the space between `String[] a` (-1 byte), change the `while` to `for` so you can put the int inside it: `for(int i=1;i>0;){...}` (-1 byte). And welcome to PPCG! :) If you haven't checked it out yet, I can recommend looking through [Tips for golfing in Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tips and for the welcome, @KevinCruijssen!

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 79 bytes

```
import System.Posix.Unistd
m=(>>usleep 500000).putStrLn
g=m"12:00">>m"--:--">>g
```

`m` is a helper function that waits half a second before printing its argument. The main function `g` calls `m "12:00"`, then `m "--:--"` and then itself again.

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 61 bytes

```
lbla
def p printLine
p 12:00
wait 500
p --:--
wait 500
GOTO a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@5@TlJPIlZKaplCgUFCUmVfik5mXylWgYGhkZWDAVZ6YWaJgCmQUKOjqWunqIgTc/UP8FRL//wcA)

Unfortunately TIO will just do nothing forever, as it waits until execution to print this. But, if you are eager to test, you can use the GitHub link.

Answer (score 1):

### [Arduino CC](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage), 79 bytes

```
void loop(){Serial.print("12:00");delay(500);Serial.print("--:--");delay(500);}
```

I have no experience with C/C++, so I don't really know how I can golf this.

Comment: You could group  `Serial.print` and `delay` into one separated function.

Comment: @F.Hauri, for me it ended up being the same length

Answer (score 1):

### [Processing](https://processing.org), 69 bytes

```
void draw(){println("12:00");delay(500);println("--:--");delay(500);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 68 Bytes

```
import time
while 1:
 for i in'12:00','--:--':print i;time.sleep(.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>35</s> <s>31</s> 30 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Full program.

```apl
{⌽⍵⊣⎕←5↑⍵⊣⎕DL÷2}⍣≡'12:00--:--'
```

`'12:00--:--'` a string

`{`...`}⍣≡` Repeatedly apply the below anonymous function until two successive results are identical (i.e. never)

`÷2` reciprocal of two (one half)

`⎕DL` **D**e**l**ay that many seconds (returns elapsed time)

`⊣` discard that in favor of

`⍵` the argument

`5↑` take the first five characters

`⎕←` display with newline

`⊣` discard that in favor of

`⌽⍵` reverse argument (implicitly returned)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 77 bytes

```
#import<windows.h>
i;f(){for(;;i^=1)Sleep(83*printf(i?"\r--:--":"\r12:00"));}
```

Comment: Just curious, don't you need to write the complete program i.e. include main()?

Comment: @6packkid: If not explicitly specified the default is program or function. See this meta discussion: [Default for Code Golf: Program, Function or Snippet?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet)

Answer (score 1):

### R  <s>69</s>    <s>65</s>  61 bytes

<s>`y=1;while(1){cat('\r',c('12:00','--:--')[y]);Sys.sleep(.5);y=(y==1)+1}`</s>

<s>`while(1){cat('\r12:00');Sys.sleep(.5);cat('\r--:--');Sys.sleep(.5)}`</s>

`f=Sys.sleep;while(1){cat('\r12:00');f(.5);cat('\r--:--');f(.5)}`

First time using the `f = blah_function()` trick, and it saved a few bytes. Used `\r` to replace existing string.

Fairly simple implementation:

```
f = Sys.sleep;      #store function for repeated usage
while(1){
    cat('\r12:00'); #print 12
    f(.5);          #sleep
    cat('\r--:--'); #print --
    f(.5)           #sleep again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## GameMaker Language, 47 bytes

```
a="12:00"if 9<c mod 20a="--:--"draw_text(0,0,a)
```

(Assuming a room speed of 20 fps)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 100 bytes

```
object C extends App{var p=1>2;while(2>1){p= !p;println(if(p)"12:00"else"--:--");Thread.sleep(500)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang, 79 bytes

```
def d datetime.wait 500
def w io.writeln
label 1
w "12:00"
d
w "--:--"
d
goto 1
```

---

And here's a version in 125 bytes that actually clears the screen each time and blinks:

```
set z string.char 8
def d datetime.wait 500
set z z+z+z+z+z
label 1
io.write "12:00"
d
io.write z+"--:--"
d
io.write z
goto 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 49

```
while 1 {lmap x 12:00\ --:-- {puts $x;after 500}}
```

Can be tried on https://goo.gl/8gXPzC

Thanks to people on tcl IRC channel.

## tcl, 51

```
while 1 {puts 12:00;after 500;puts --:--;after 500}
```

Can be tried on https://goo.gl/Hb3sHq

Answer (score 1):

### HTML + CSS, <strike>147, 148</strike> 142 Bytes

```css
*{font-family:Courier;left 0;background-color:white;position:absolute}@keyframes d{0%,49%{left:0}50%,to{left:-10em}}a{animation:d 1s infinite}
```

```html
12:00<a>--:--
```

### Explanation:

Basically, this uses two HTML elements: A text node containing `12:00` and an `<a>` tag containing `--:--`.

The selector in the CSS applies to both elements, giving both absolute positioning `0` to the left. This allows both elements to overlap. Then, I gave both elements a monospace font, making each take up equal widths. Finally, I set the background color to white, making sure that the `<a>` tag hides the text it overlaps.

Then, I use an animation to move the `<a>` tag offscreen every .5 seconds. To do this, the animation lasts one second, and shows the tag for the first 49%, then hides it for the last 50%.

Oh - finally, `Courier` is shorter than `monospace`, saving 3 bytes, but it might not work in all browsers/operating systems.

#### Update: +1 Byte

Turns out that Monaco isn't on everyone's computer. changed to using `Courier` instead at the expense of a byte.

#### Update: -6 Bytes

Forgot to remove a bit of whitespace. Oops.

### Non minified code:

```css
* {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Courier;
  background-color: white;
}
@keyframes d {
  0%, 49% {
    left: 0
  }
  50%, to {
    left: -10em
  }
}
a{animation: d 1s infinite}
```

```html
12:00<a>--:--
```

Comment: @LuisMendo I saved 3 bytes by using the font `Monaco` instead of `monospace` :P - didn't know about support. I'll change it.

Comment: Yes, it works for me now

Comment: @LuisMendo cool. thanks a lot for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA (Win, Excel 32 bit Only), 97 Bytes

**In a module:**

Because VBA's `Application.Wait()` method cannot handle input for time periods of less than one second, a declaration of the kernel32 `sleep` method is used for the 500 ms wait period.

```vba
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal s&)
```

*Note:* 64-bit versions of VBA (VB7) require a `PtrSafe` tag after the `Declare` tag<s>, and changing the `ByVal s&` call to `ByVal s as LongPtr`</s>.

**In the vbe immediates window:**

```vba
Do:DoEvents:?"12:00":Sleep 500:?"--:--":Sleep 500:Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 48 bytes

```
for(;;usleep(5e5))echo($n^=1)?"
12:00":"
--:--";
```

Run with `-nr`.

Replace instead of multiple lines with `\r` instead of `\n` (+2 bytes):

```
for(;;usleep(5e5))echo($n^=1)?"\r12:00":"\r--:--";
```

Answer (score 1):

## REXX, <del>60</del>, 54 bytes

```
d.='--:--'
d.1='12:00'
a=1
do b=0
  sleep(.5)
  a=\a
  say d.a
  end
```

(Indented for readability)

Edit: Turns out that the most naïve solution is even shorter:

```
do b=0
say '12:00'
sleep(.5)
say '--:--'
sleep(.5)
end
```

Tested with Regina REXX interpreter; some older implementations may not have the `Delay` function at all, or it may only support whole seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## [*><>](//esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish), 30 bytes

```
cn"00:"ooo5Sdo"--:--"ooooo5Sdo
```

[Online test.](//starfish.000webhostapp.com?script=MYOwRADBBcYPYIKwGUAmcwFpPW-BSacQA)

I feel this is much simpler and more different than redstarcoder's algorithm, and thus I posted it as separate.

Replaces output in-place.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 94 bytes

Unfortunately Lua has no built-in sleep function, so a loop is necessary.

```
x=1 z=os.clock while 1 do x=-x print(x<0 and"12:00"or"--:--") y=z()+.5 repeat until z()>y end
```

As a bonus, here's a Windows only one which is 109 bytes and which clears the screen each time:

```
x=1 z=os.clock while 1 do x=-x print(x<0 and"12:00"or"--:--") y=z()+.5 repeat until z()>y os.execute"cls"end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
import time
t=0
while 1:u=t%2;v='--'*u;w=1-u;print v+'12'*w+':'+v+'00'*w;t+=1;time.sleep(.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcxBCoAgEADAe6/wEluKokKXln2OkJAlturzrY5zmRFTvgsLjilMTHbqRzyDcHslnj02Aq1BVuzkdMVc4sWiKXAeZFewg/pg7QdkRQ7/xjxnCHkx2zrGCw)

### Explanation

```
import time                                   Import the time module
t=0                                           Set a counter, 't', to 0
while 1:                                      Trigger an infinite loop
    u = t%2                                   Let 'u' be the remainder of t/2. This will alternate between 0 and 1 
    w = 1 - u                                 Let 'w' be the opposite of u
    v = '--'*u                                Python lets the repetition of strings by multiplying them by an int. Here we are either mulitplying by 1 (no effect) or 0 (turns it to an empty string)
    print v + '12'*w + ':' + v + '00'*w       Concatonating 4 strings and printing them. We are using string multiplication again on the '12' and '00'
    t += 1                                    Increment the counter variable
    time.sleep(0.5)                           Wait half a second
```

Comment: Nice answer, but take a look at [this Python solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105325/60919) to see how you could have improved it. Also see the [tips for golfing in python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>62</s> <s>58</s> 51  bytes

```
: p . cr .5 sleep ; : f "12:00" p "--:--" p recurse ;
```

When invoked, the word `f` will display blinking twelve according the "[new line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vhiR.gif)" format. This code leverages "tail-call elimination" implemented in 8th.

The following code (95 bytes long) will let word `f` display blinking twelve according the "[replacing the former string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqWzT.gif)" format:

```
: p 0 0 con:gotoxy con:print ; 
: f con:cls repeat "12:00" p .5 sleep "--:--" p .5 sleep again ;
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 35 bytes

```
WAIT 30?"12:00
WAIT 30?"--:--
EXEC.
```

`WAIT` times are in frames (1/60 second), and `EXEC.` restarts the program (equivilant to `EXEC 0` which runs the code that's in slot 0)

Version that clears the screen and adds 6 bytes:

```
WAIT 30CLS?"12:00
WAIT 30CLS?"--:--
EXEC.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [PKod](https://github.com/PKTINOS/PKod), 26 bytes

PKod is an esoteric language that only has one accessible variable

**Code:**

```
l12=:o00yyl=-oo=:o=-ooyy<

Explanation:
l - if first char in code, print any NOP chars found
12 - two NOP chars to print
=: - set variable as :
00 - two more NOP chars
o - print variable's corresponding ascii char
y - wait 0.25 seconds
l - if not first char in code, clear the console
=-oo - set variable as - and print twice
< - go back to the start of the code
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"12:00"…--:û[s=₄;.W
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydDIysBA6VHDMl1dq8O7o4ttHzW1WOuF//8PAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
"12:00"            # Push string "12:00"
       …--:        # Push string "--:"
           û       # Palindromize it to "--:--"
[                  # Loop indefinitely:
 s                 #  Swap the two values on the stack
  =                #  Print the top with trailing newline (without popping)
   ₄;              #  Push 1000 halved: 500
     .W            #  Sleep that many ms
```

`"12:00"` could alternatively be `Žmy3'::` for the same byte-count.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 51 bytes

```c
f(i){puts(i?"12:00":"--:--");usleep(500000);f(!i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcGxCoAgEADQOb@inO6GAwtavKFvEdE4MBG0Sfx2o/c8@eTyPWcEwV7eVkEuvR/WGG01kSXSyG9NIRQ4zQ85wibIY0pu6@MkA3a1REBWY34)

Comment: This doesn't work. `5e5` is a double. The implicit declaration of `usleep` will cause Clang to assume it is `int usleep(double)`, and depending on the calling convention, it will either wait for a garbage value or call it with 549606724824 (`5e5` interpreted as an integer) which is an EINVAL.

Comment: Suggest `1<<19` instead of `500000`

Comment: @ceilingcat `2^19` doesn't exactly equal `500,000`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 103 bytes

```
import'dart:io';f({i=1}){while(i>0){print(i++%2>0?"12:00":"--:--");sleep(Duration(milliseconds:500));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdLCsMgEADQuwglMwRhEuhGabrpRaQaOuAPtXQhnt3m7Z41pc3JIafSFntFcVr0CZ0f28D@@7B3wAdhz4VjA17X237QU2y7IhJKSKmkFKirdy7D61tM4xQhsPdc3TtFW9WdCFGPMYPhCNhPuDb/)

Sometimes I hate how verbose and strongly typed Dart has to be :D

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 27 bytes

```
500t@ßÃOq"12:00--:--"ò5 gT°
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=NTAwdEDfw09xIjEyOjAwLS06LS0i8jUgZ1Sw&input=)

```
500t@ßÃ                         :Run the programme again in 500ms
       Oq                       :Clear the output
         "12:00--:--"ò5         :Split the string "12:00--:--" into chunks of length 5
                        gT°     :Get the element at index T (initially 0), postfix incremented
```

Comment: Not quite real-time output, @LuisMendo; explanation added. Figured the other version wouldn't be valid for that reason, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), (until version 5.0.1), 64 bytes

This piece of code prints the strings on a new line. Only works in GNU AWK up to version 5.0.1, while the `time` extension (module) was not obsolete.

```
@load"time";BEGIN{for(;;){sleep(.5);print++t%2?"12:00":"--:--"}}
```

### Clearing the screen with `clear` command (80 bytes)

This example uses the `clear` command, not native to Awk.

```
@load"time";BEGIN{for(;;){sleep(.5);system("clear");print++t%2?"12:00":"--:--"}}
```

### Clearing the screen with `\33[H\33[2J\33[3J` (85 bytes)

But don't despair if there is no command to clear the screen on your system. Just hard code it. `\33` is the ASCII for Escape in octal.

```
@load"time";BEGIN{for(;;){sleep(.5);print"\33[H\33[2J\33[3J"(++t%2?"12:00":"--:--")}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 51 bytes

```basic
LOCATE 1
IF TIMER*2MOD 2THEN?"12:00"ELSE?"--:--
RUN
```

[Try it at Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack) (but note that it's an infinite loop, so there's no way to exit the program besides closing/refreshing your browser).

Displays both strings on the top line of the screen. If you're using actual QBasic rather than QB64, you'll notice that the program doesn't clear the screen first, so there may be other junk present as well. This issue can be fixed at a cost of 8 bytes: add `CLS:DO:` at the beginning of the program and change `RUN` to `LOOP`.

#### Explanation

Waiting for a fraction of a second is hard in QBasic, as [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105469/16766) [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105327/16766) have mentioned, since the built-in `SLEEP` command only takes integers. However, `TIMER` (which represents the number of seconds since midnight) is a floating-point value. Whenever its fractional part is less than .5, we'll print `--:--`, and whenever its fractional part is greater than .5, we'll print `12:00`. Conveniently, the `MOD` operator truncates to integer, so we can use `TIMER * 2 MOD 2` and get values of `0` and `1`.

This approach prints many, many times per second, but most of the time it's printing the same value over itself, so nothing changes.

Ungolfed and commented:

```basic
LOCATE 1                  ' Move the cursor to the top row
IF TIMER * 2 MOD 2 THEN   ' Alternates between 0 and 1 with a period of 1 second
  PRINT "12:00"
ELSE
  PRINT "--:--"
END IF
RUN                       ' Restart the program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>22</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
å√Φ←mp═╠╗⌐fâêÇY)♀╗}%
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=86fbe81b6d70cdccbba96683888059290cbb7d25&i=&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
…--:ûŽmy3'::[=s₄;.W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMyXV2rw7uP7s2tNFa3soq2LX7U1GKtF/7/PwA) Outputs each string on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

### under construction, I missed the 1 second delay

### awk, <s>35</s>34 bytes (+11 for `12:00 --:--`)

```
{for(;++i;i=i%2)print$(i)"\033[A"}
```

`for` loop alternates `i`'s value between 1 and 2. `echo` feeds the values to the program into fields `$1`and `$2`, we then `print $(i)`. Try it:

```
$ echo 12:00 --:-- | awk '{for(;++i;i=i%2)print$(i)"\033[A"}'
```

**Edit**: Thanks for the ANSI tip to @F.Hauri.

Comment: Ansi sequence use 1 as default, so the `1` is useless in `\033[A`.

Answer (score 0):

### C 79 Bytes

```
f(){while(1){printf("\n12:00");usleep(500000);printf("\n--:--");usleep(500000);}}
```

so the main would look like `int main(){ f(); return 0;}`

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Just so you know, the downvote was cast automatically by the Community user when you edited your answer. [I consider this a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276269/170332).

Comment: You have to write a full program or a function, so you'd have to wrap your code in `f(){...}` or something. Also, the spec allows printing each output on a separate line, so `system("clear");` is not required.

Comment: You still need the while loop in your submission. Also, you cannot pass a float to `usleep`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
import time;x=0
while 1:x=not x;print("12:00--:--"[x*5:x*5+5]);time.sleep(0.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu7CoAgFADQva@QJi2uaOGi@CXRKCj4wi5kX281nPHUB33J@xgh1dKQYEjOdCum24foiNTd5oKkm9pCRjrLTQsBoAHmoy9Kf1Z1MvM/fkXnKhVcsTFe)